# How do you query object collections in Java (Criteria/SQL-like)?

Tags: java, sql, collections

Suppose you have a collection of a few hundred in-memory objects and you need to query this List to return objects matching some SQL or Criteria like query. For example, you might have a List of Car objects and you want to return all cars made during the 1960s, with a license plate that starts with AZ, ordered by the name of the car model.

I know about [JoSQL](http://josql.sourceforge.net/), has anyone used this, or have any experience with other/homegrown solutions?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I have used [Apache Commons JXPath](http://commons.apache.org/jxpath/) in a production application. It allows you to apply XPath expressions to graphs of objects in Java.

Comment: it is an XPath expression interpreter

Answer (score 27):

Filtering is one way to do this, as discussed in other answers.

Filtering is not scalable though. On the surface time complexity would appear to be O(*n*) (i.e. already not scalable if the number of objects in the collection will grow), but actually because one *or more* tests need to be applied to each object depending on the query, time complexity more accurately is O(*n t*) where *t* is the number of tests to apply to each object.

So performance will degrade as additional objects are added to the collection, *and/or* as the number of tests in the query increases.

There is another way to do this, using indexing and set theory.

One approach is to **build *indexes* on the *fields*** within the objects stored in your collection and which you will subsequently test in your query.

Say you have a collection of `Car` objects and every `Car` object has a field `color`. Say your query is the equivalent of "`SELECT * FROM cars WHERE Car.color = 'blue'`". You could build an index on `Car.color`, which would basically look like this:

```
'blue' -> {Car{name=blue_car_1, color='blue'}, Car{name=blue_car_2, color='blue'}}
'red'  -> {Car{name=red_car_1, color='red'}, Car{name=red_car_2, color='red'}}
```

Then given a query `WHERE Car.color = 'blue'`, the set of blue cars could be retrieved in O(*1*) time complexity. If there were additional tests in your query, you could then test each car in that *candidate set* to check if it matched the remaining tests in your query. Since the candidate set is likely to be significantly smaller than the entire collection, time complexity is *less than* O(*n*) (in the engineering sense, see comments below). Performance does not degrade *as much*, when additional objects are added to the collection. But this is still not perfect, read on.

Another approach, is what I would refer to as a ***standing query index***. To explain: with conventional iteration and filtering, the collection is iterated and every object is tested to see if it matches the query. So filtering is like running a query over a collection. A standing query index would be the other way around, where the collection is instead run over the query, but only once for each object in the collection, even though the collection could be queried any number of times.

A *standing query index* would be like registering a query with some sort of *intelligent collection*, such that as objects are added to and removed from the collection, the collection would automatically test each object against all of the standing queries which have been registered with it. If an object matches a standing query then the collection could add/remove it to/from a set dedicated to storing objects matching that query. Subsequently, objects matching any of the registered queries could be retrieved in O(*1*) time complexity.

The information above is taken from [CQEngine (Collection Query Engine)](https://github.com/npgall/cqengine). This basically is a NoSQL query engine for retrieving objects from Java collections using SQL-like queries, without the overhead of iterating through the collection. It is built around the ideas above, plus some more. Disclaimer: I am the author. It's open source and in maven central.

Comment: Good answer, but you should edit the following statement: "Since the candidate set is likely to be significantly smaller than the entire collection, time complexity is less than O(n)." This is incorrect. Let's assume you have 5 different colors. Then the size of the candidate set is on average 0.2n. This results in O(0.2n), and O(0.2n) = O(n), see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Multiplication_by_a_constant. Scalability improves only, if the number of *different* values increases significantly (e.g. you get *significantly* more different colors as the total set grows).

Comment: Interesting. My time complexity function is intended to be an actual engineering-style formula. If we follow the strict Big O Notation rule for "multiplication by a scalar" per wikipedia, and so change the formula from O(0.2n) to O(n), then we would discard information about the merits of this approach versus others, when n < infinity. I guess my statement is more from an engineering perspective versus a theoretical computer science perspective. I suppose the function should really be O(selectivity(c, n) n) or something anyway. Thanks for the interesting point though, I'll look at re-wording.

Answer (score 6):

yes, I know it's an old post, but technologies appear everyday and the answer will change in the time.

I think this is a good problem to solve it with LambdaJ. You can find it here:
http://code.google.com/p/lambdaj/

Here you have an example:

**LOOK FOR ACTIVE CUSTOMERS     // (Iterable version)**

```
List<Customer> activeCustomers = new ArrayList<Customer>();  
for (Customer customer : customers) {  
  if (customer.isActive()) {  
    activeCusomers.add(customer);  
  }  
}
```

**LambdaJ version**

```
List<Customer> activeCustomers = select(customers, 
                                        having(on(Customer.class).isActive()));
```

Of course, having this kind of beauty impacts in the performance (a little... an average of 2 times), but can you find a more readable code?

It has many many features, another example could be sorting:

**Sort Iterative**

```
List<Person> sortedByAgePersons = new ArrayList<Person>(persons);
Collections.sort(sortedByAgePersons, new Comparator<Person>() {
        public int compare(Person p1, Person p2) {
           return Integer.valueOf(p1.getAge()).compareTo(p2.getAge());
        }
});
```

**Sort with lambda**

```
List<Person> sortedByAgePersons = sort(persons, on(Person.class).getAge());
```

---

**Update**: after java 8 you can use out of the box lambda expressions, like:

```java
List<Customer> activeCustomers = customers.stream()
                                          .filter(Customer::isActive)
                                          .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: I heard that you can use it but there are some bugs. You should post con lambdaj forum before trying it since it could be risky. By the way, keep in mind that using lambdaj impacts on the performance. In some examples it takes 6 times more to achieve your tasks, in others 1.5 times.

Answer (score 3):

Continuing the `Comparator` theme, you may also want to take a look at the [Google Collections](http://code.google.com/p/google-collections/) API.  In particular, they have an interface called [Predicate](http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Predicate.html), which serves a similar role to `Comparator`, in that it is a simple interface that can be used by a filtering method, like [Sets.filter](http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Sets.html#filter(java.util.Set,%20com.google.common.base.Predicate)).  They include a whole bunch of composite predicate implementations, to do ANDs, ORs, etc.

Depending on the size of your data set, it may make more sense to use this approach than a SQL or external relational database approach.

Answer (score 2):

If you need a single concrete match, you can have the class implement Comparator, then create a standalone object with all the hashed fields included and use it to return the index of the match.  When you want to find more than one (potentially) object in the collection, you'll have to turn to a library like JoSQL (which has worked well in the trivial cases I've used it for).

In general, I tend to embed Derby into even my small applications, use Hibernate annotations to define my model classes and let Hibernate deal with caching schemes to keep everything fast.

Comment: Embedding an in-memory database like Derby sounds like a good idea, particulary since Derby is now a part of the JDK. Introducing Hibernate to the mix would be a bit overkill for my use. I'd just go with SQL/JDBC i guess.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a Comparator that takes a range of years and license plate pattern as input parameters.  Then just iterate through your collection and copy the objects that match.  You'd likely end up making a whole package of custom Comparators with this approach.

Comment: Could you elaborate please? I understand how to create a custom Comparator and implement the compare method to compare on some property. But I'm not sure how to accomplish this with multiple input parameters?

Answer (score 0):

The `Comparator` option is not bad, especially if you use anonymous classes (so as not to create redundant classes in the project), but eventually when you look at the flow of comparisons, it's pretty much just like looping over the entire collection yourself, specifying exactly the conditions for matching items:

```
if (Car car : cars) {
    if (1959 < car.getYear() && 1970 > car.getYear() &&
            car.getLicense().startsWith("AZ")) {
        result.add(car);
    }
}
```

Then there's the sorting... that might be a pain in the backside, but luckily there's class `Collections` and its `sort` methods, one of which receives a `Comparator`...

Comment: This is the approach I am using now and it quickly gets unwieldly when the criterias increases. But it's probably okay for the simple example.