# Data and storage design and modeling for filters by details

Tags: database, database-design, data-structures, data-modeling

## TL;DR

I have architecture issue which boils down to filtering entities by predefined set of common filters. Input is: set of **products**. Each product has **details**. I need to design filtering engine so that I can (easily and fast) resolve a task: 
**"Filter out collection of products with specified details"**

## Requirements

User may specify whatever filtering is possible with support of precedence and nested filters. So, bare example is `(weight=X AND (color='red' OR color='green')) OR price<1000` The requests should go via [`HTTP`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol) / [`REST`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer), but that's insignificant (it only adds an issue with translating filters from [URI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_resource_identifier) to some internal model). Any comparison operators should be supported (like equality, inequality, less than etc.)

## Specifics

**Model**

There is no fixed model definition - in fact I am free to chose one. To make it simpler I am using simple `key=>value` for details. So it goes at the very minimum to:

```
class Value extends Entity implements Arrayable
{
    protected $key;

    protected $value;
    //getters/setters for key/value here
}
```

for simple value for product detail and something like

```
class Product extends Entity implements Arrayable
{
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var Value[]
     */
    protected $details;

    //getters/setters, more properties that are omitted
}
```

for the product. Now, regarding data model, there is a first question: **How to design filtering model?**. I have a simple idea of implementing it as a let's say, recursive iterator which will be a [tree regular structure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_%28data_structure%29) according to incoming user request. The difficulties which I certainly need to solve here are:

- Quickly build the model structure out from user request
- Possibility for easy modification of the structure
- Easy translate of chosen filters data model to chosen storage (see below)

Last point in the list above is probably the most important part as storage routines will be most time-consuming and therefore filters data model should fit in such structure. That means storage has always higher priority and if data model can not fit into some storage design that allows to resolve the issue - then data model should be changed.

**Storage**

As a storage I want to use [`NoSQL`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL)+[`RDBMS`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database_management_system) which is [***Postgree 9.4***](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/What%27s_new_in_PostgreSQL_9.4) for example. So that will allow to use [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) for storing details. I do not want to use [`EAV`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model) in any case, that is why pure relational DBMS isn't an option (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20782760/difference-between-two-table-structure/20783125#20783125) why). There is one important thing - **products** may contain **stocks** which leads to the situation that I have basically two ways:

- If I design products as a single entity with their stocks (pretty logical), then I can not go "storage" + "indexer" approach because this produces outdated state as indexer (such as [***SOLR***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Solr)) needs to update and reindex data
- Design with separate entities. That means - to separate whatever can be cached from whatever that can not. First part then can go to indexer (and details probably can go to there, so we are filtering by them) and non-cacheable part will go somewhere else.

And the question for storage part would be, of course: **which one to chose?**

Good thing about first approach is that the internal API is simple, internal structures are simple and scalable because they then can easily be abstracted from storage layer. Bad thing is that then I need this "magic solution" which will allow to use "just storage" instead of "storage+indexer". "Magic" here means to somehow design indexes or some additional data-structures (I was thinking about hashing, but it isn't helpful against range queries) in storage that will resolve filtering requests.

On the other hand second solution will allow to use search engine to resolve filtering task inside itself but producing some gap when data will be outdated there. And of course now the data layer needs to be implemented the way it will somehow know about which part of model goes to which storage (so stocks to one storage, details to another etc)

## Summary

- What can be a proper data model to design filtering?
- Which approach should be used to resolve the issue on the storage level: storage+indexer with separate products model or only storage with monolithic products model? Or may be something else?
- If go the approach with storage only - is it possible to design storage so it will be possible to filter out products easily by any set of details?
- If go with the indexer, what will fit better for this issue? (There is a good comparison between solr and sphinx [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1284083/choosing-a-stand-alone-full-text-search-server-sphinx-or-solr), but it's '15 now while it was made in '09 so for sure it is outdated)

Any links, related blogposts or articles are very welcome.

*As a P.S.: I did a search across SO but faced barely-relevant suggestions/topics so far (for example [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1622474/design-pattern-for-filtering-a-collection-of-items)). I am not expecting a silver bullet here as it is always boils down to some trade-off, but however question looks very standard so there should be good insights already. Please, guide me - I tried to "[ask google](https://www.google.de/search?q=data%20design%20for%20filters)" with some luck but that was not enough yet.*

*P.P.S. feel free to edit tags or redirect question to proper SE resource if SO is not a good idea for such kind of questions. And I am not asking language-specific solution, so if you are not using [**PHP**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP) - it does not matter, design has nothing to do with the language*

Answer (score 1):

My preferred solution would be to split the entities - your second approach.  The stable data would be held in Cassandra (or Solr or Elastic etc), while the volatile stock data would be held in (ideally) an in-memory database like Redis or Memcache that supports compare-and-swap / transactions (or Dynamo or Voldemort etc if the stock data won't fit in memory).  You won't need to worry too much about the consistency of the stable data since presumably it changes rarely if ever, so you can choose a scalable but not entirely consistent database like Cassandra; meanwhile you can choose a less scalable but more consistent database for the volatile stock data.

Comment: Thanks, but so if you're suggesting approach with index-server, could you please give a brief overview for them like comparison? Of course I read about most popular ones like solr/sphinx already but it would be good to see others experience

Comment: @AlmaDo Most of my experience has been with Cassandra and Elastic - my understanding is that Solr is similar to Elastic.  Elastic is excellent for text search but is not recommended as a primary database (by Elastic), but because your data is mostly static I doubt you'd run into problems.  Cassandra is essentially a multi-dimensional key value store, i.e. a relational database where only non-null columns appear on disk - it is "eventually  consistent" meaning that it scales to multiple server nodes but not every node is guaranteed to have the latest data, which shouldn't be a problem with...

Comment: @AlmaDo ...your workload because it's read heavy.  If you think that this eventual consistency  model might be a concern then you could query the Redis (or whatever) database to see if the product code exists, if it does then query Cassandra with a low-consistency read, and if this read fails then query Cassandra with a high-consistency  read (i.e. query every database node).