# Java Get Multiple Items From Collection

Tags: java, collections, filter

Do Java collections have a built-in method to return multiple items from that collection?  For example, the list below has *n* elements, some of which are duplicated in the list.  How could I get all elements where the value = "one"?  I realize it would be very easy to write my own method to achieve such functionality, I just wanted to make sure I am not missing a built in method to do this.

```
List<String> ls=new ArrayList<String>();
ls.add("one");
ls.add("two");
ls.add("three");
ls.add("one");
ls.add("one");

//some type of built in function????
//ls.getItems("one");
//should return elements 0,3,4
```

Thanks

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/122105/java-what-is-the-best-way-to-filter-a-collection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Collections have [Predicates](http://www.developer.com/open/article.php/10930_3735441_5/The-Google-Collections-Library.htm) for this purpose.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a built-in method, but **[Apache Commons has a `select` method](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/CollectionUtils.html#select-java.lang.Iterable-org.apache.commons.collections4.Predicate-)** in [**`CollectionUtils`**](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/CollectionUtils.html) that will get all the elements that match some criterion. Example usage:

```
List<String> l = new ArrayList<String>();

// add some elements...

// Get all the strings that start with the letter "e".
Collection beginsWithE = CollectionUtils.select(l, new Predicate() {
  public boolean evaluate(Object o) {
    return ((String) o).toLowerCase().startsWith("e");
  }
);
```

Comment: At the moment I don't see any advantage of Apache Collections over Google Collections. They stopped developing this library and it's the main problem.

Answer (score 2):

In this example, it's enough to know the number of times "one" appears in the list, which you can get with `java.util.Collections.frequency(ls, "one")`.

You could also have been using a `Multiset` from google-collections, and called `m.count("one")`, which would be much more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could do the trick of retaining the elements of this list which are in another list with the retainall method of Collection class [link text](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#retainAll(java.util.Collection)). In the other list you can add only the "one" object.

```
List<String> ls=new ArrayList<String>();
ls.add("one");
ls.add("two");
ls.add("three");
ls.add("one");
ls.add("one");

List<String> listToCompare = new ArrayList<String>();
listToCompare.add("one");
ls.retainAll(listToCompare);
```