# Getting a view of a List based on a property

Tags: java

I need to write a method that returns a view of a List(java.util.List). The returned view should contain only those elements in the input List that returns true when tested with the isSuccessful() method.

```
List<Entity> getSuccessfulEntities(List<Entity> entities)
{
  //Return a List view of entities, each element of which returns true for isSuccessful(entity)
}
```

I have looked at Collections and List API but couldn't find any facility for this. Any out of box thought?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing (at least that I know of) in the Java standard library, but you could use 
[`com.google.common.collect.Collections2`](http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Collections2.html)`.filter()` and `Predicate`, which is just defined as:

```
public interface Predicate<T> { boolean apply(T input); }
```

Changes to the unfiltered and filtered `Collection` affect one another. Sample code:

```
Predicate<Entity> isSuccessful = new Predicate<Entity>() {
    public boolean apply(Entity e) {
        return e.isSuccessful();
    }
};

Collection<Entity> successfulEntities = filter(entities, isSuccessful);
```

*Related:* [Java: What is the best way to filter a Collection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122105/java-what-is-the-best-way-to-filter-a-collection)

Comment: This creates an entirely new ArrayList. I only want a view(unmodifiable) that actually makes use of the original List.

Answer (score 1):

The generic way would be to define a Predicate interface that tests an instance of T and returns a boolean.

Then take an instance of an implementation of Predicate as a parameter to getSuccesfulEntities and iterate over the collection, calling a method on the predicate to determine if it should be in the returned collection.