# Filter java.util.Collection in Java

Tags: java, collections

I wrote a util class to filter elements in `java.util.Collection` as follows:

```
public class Util{
  public static <T> void filter(Collection<T> l, Filter<T> filter) {
    Iterator<T> it= l.iterator();
    while(it.hasNext()) {
      if(!filter.match(it.next())) {
        it.remove();
      }
    }
  }
}

public interface Filter<T> {
  public boolean match(T o);
}
```

Questions:

1. Do you think it's necessary to write the method?
2. Any improvement about the method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should allow any `Filter<? super T>` not just `Filter<T>`.

Clients might also want to have a method that returns a new Collection instead:

```
public static <T> Collection<T> filter(Collection<T> unfiltered, 
    Filter<? super T> filter)
```

Answer (score 4):

1. No. The [guava-libraries](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) already have this functionality. See [`Iterables.filter(iterableCollection, predicate)`](http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html#filter%28java.lang.Iterable,%20com.google.common.base.Predicate%29) where the `Predicate` implements the filtering

Answer (score 1):

Whether it's necessary depends on what you want to achieve. If you can use other third party libs like Google Collections, then no. If it's planned to be a one-off, then probably not. If you plan on creating different filters, then yep, looks like a good approach to keep things modular and cohesive.

One suggestion - you might want to return a Collection - that way, you have the option of returning a new filtered Collection rather than mutating the original Collection. That could be handy if you need to use it in a concurrent context.

You might also look at the responses to [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122105/java-what-is-the-best-way-to-filter-a-collection).

Answer (score 1):

Looks nice - but we can't decide, if it's 'necessary' to write it (OK, you actually wrote it ;) )

The `remove()` method is not always implemented, it is labelled *(optional)*. Some Iterators just throw an `UnsupportedOperationException`. You should catch it or convert it to a custom exception saying, that this collection can't be filtered.

And then you could change the method signature to

```
public static <T> void filter(Iterable<T> i, Filter<T> filter)
```

because iterators are not limited to Collections. With this utility method you could filter every 'container' that provides an iterator which allows remove operations.

Answer (score 1):

> > Do you think it's necessary to write the method?

If you don't mind using a third party library then no.

Some suggestions for third party libraries that provide this functionality:

You might want to look at [Functional Java](http://functionaljava.org/) which provides `filter` plus many other higher order functions found in true-blue functional languages.

Example:

```
List<Person> adults = filter(people, new F1<Person, Boolean>() {
  public Boolean f(Person p) {
    return p.getAge() > 18;
  }
});
```

Another alternative is using [lambdaj](http://code.google.com/p/lambdaj/) - a library with similar goals but is much more concise than Functional Java. lambdaj doesn't cover as much ground as Functional Java though.

Example:

```
List<Person> adults = filter(having(on(Person.class).getAge(), greaterThan(18)), people);
```

Answer (score 1):

Regarding question 1 there are already a lot of collection libraries. Filtering is offered by instance by apache common-collections [CollectionUtils](http://commons.apache.org/collections/api/org/apache/commons/collections/CollectionUtils.html) and google collections [Iterables](http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/index.html?com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html) .

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be cool to have a `visit(T o)` method defined in your `Filter<T>` interface. That way the filter implementation can decide what action to take on the visited object when there is a match.