# Android Filtering a List of Objects

Tags: java, android, list, filter

My question is similar to: [java Best way to Filter list of object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4215645/java-best-way-to-filter-list-of-object)

> I have a list of objects say Sales. I want only the Sales objects
>   whose Product matches the ones in another list, say saleProductList.
>
> Other than looping, is there a better way to do it.

However I wish to be able to able to do the filtering with code accessible to android, e.g. The libraries would need to play nice with the android OS and run on the android OS. I'm hoping to avoid making home cooked code for a problem I assume is common, any suggestions?

Comment: depends on the specifics of your problem. you probably have a database. in this case the best way is to filter using your queries.

Comment: Do you mean better in terms of coding style or better in terms of efficiency ? There is no way to know if a product matches another without going through all of them.

Comment: search on listview items?

Comment: @DeepakBala, I'm looking for something like:  newList = bigList.filter(clientName, "Bob");   in essence, similar to how you can add where statements to queries... if there is no easy way to do this, I'll rely more on the db like how njzk2 suggests.

Comment: @VenomFangs Writing an API to do that should not be complicated, but if you have a DB, I'd still go with that. You can save CPU and memory just getting the right information from the database the first time.

Answer (score 11):

```
// mFinalList will contain filtered data.

List<Object> mFinalList=new ArrayList<>();
  
for (Object person : listData) {
    if (person.getNameType().equalsIgnoreCase("somename")) {
        mFinalList.add(person);
    }
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it is better to include an explanation for the  code to be easier understood.

Comment: You'd want to do checks in your if statement to protect against possible NPEs.

Answer (score 6):

If your goal is to filter a list (`List` or `ArrayList`) on a simple constraint and diplay the data in a `ListView` you can directly use the interface `Filterable` in your adapter as below:

```
public class AdapterFilterable extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {

@Override
public Filter getFilter() {

    Filter filter = new Filter() {

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {

            if (results != null && results.values != null) {

                _arrayList = (List<object>) results.values;
            }
            else {
                _arrayList = ApplicationGlobal._dataManager.get_ArraylistFull();
            }
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {

            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
            List<YourObject> filteredList = new ArrayList<YourObject>();

            //Do your filtering operation with the constraint String
            //Return result for publishResults to use it
       
            results.count = filteredList.size();
            results.values = filteredList;

            return results;
        }
    };
    return filter;
}
```

To use the filter, like when searching in a list or just filtering it with a constraint, you just need:

```
_yourAdapter.getFilter().filter(String yourConstraintString);
```

Else if you want to filter on complex data you can simply filter with a `for` loop and then do your `notifyDataChanged();`.

Hope it helps.