# How to filter the results stored in a "Query" type with an unindexed field?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, objectify

Using datastore query, I have filtered based on brandId (Indexed field) and have stored data in "Query" as-

```
Query<AnalyticsLogsAgr> query =  ofy().cache(false).load().type(AnalyticsLogsAgr.class).filter("date >=",  d).filter("date <", d1)
                .filter("type", type).filter("brandId", brandId).limit(1000);
```

Now once I have got the data in Query, I want to filter it again in my code based on an unindexed field (listingId). How can I do this ?

Comment: Please someone answer it soon.

Answer (score 1):

If i understand your question correctly it has nothing to do with Objectify or App Engine. Your question is actually: How do i filter a list of Objects by an object attribute?

If it is not, because you don't have a list yet, that's because you're missing a `.list()`at the end of your query.

Your actual question is answered more than once on stackoverflow:
Try: [java Best way to Filter list of object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4215645/java-best-way-to-filter-list-of-object)