# List filtering : recreate from empty list, or copy and delete elements?

Tags: java, arrays, performance, optimization, arraylist

I have an `ArrayList`, and I need to filter it (only to **remove** some elements).

I **can't modify the original list**.

What is my best option regarding **performances** :

- Recreate another list from the original one, and remove items from it :

code :

```
List<Foo> newList = new ArrayList<Foo>(initialList);
for (Foo item : initialList) {
    if (...) {
        newList.remove(item);
    }
}
```

- Create an empty list, and add items :

code :

```
List<Foo> newList = new ArrayList<Foo>(initialList.size());
for (Foo item : initialList) {
    if (...) {
        newList.add(item);
    }
}
```

**Which of these options is the best ?** Should I use anything else than `ArrayList` ? (I can't change the type of the original list though)

As a side note, approximatively 80% of the items will be kept in the list. The list contains from 1 to around 20 elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I'm only get suggestions here, I decided to run my own bench to be sure.

Here are the conclusions (with an `ArrayList` of `String`).

- Solution 1, remove items from the copy : **2400 ms**.
- Solution 2, create an empty list and fill it : **1600 ms**. `newList = new ArrayList<Foo>();`
- Solution 3, same as 2, except you set the initial size of the List : **1530 ms**. `newList = new ArrayList<Foo>(initialList.size());`
- Solution 4, same as 2, except you set the initial size of the List + 1 : **1500 ms**. `newList = new ArrayList<Foo>(initialList.size() + 1);` (as explained by @Soronthar)

Source : http://pastebin.com/c2C5c9Ha

Comment: You've ended up identifying what I came here to recommend, so I'm just commenting.  However please note that reliable benchnmarking is very tricky in modern languages.

Comment: Sadly your benchmark is deeply flawed - see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/504103/how-do-i-write-a-correct-micro-benchmark-in-java) for an explanation. But still it's obvious that the 3rd solution (the +1 is useless - that would only make a difference if you didn't filter any item) will be the best.

Answer (score 2):

Best option is to go with what is easiest to write and maintain.

If performance is problem, you should profile the application afterwards and not to optimize prematurely.

In addition, I'd use filtering from library like google-collections or commons collections to make the code more readable:

```
Collection<T> newCollection = Collections2.filter(new Predicate<T>() {
    public boolean apply(T item) {
        return (...); // apply your test here
    }
});
```

Anyway, as it seems you are optimizing for the performance, I'd go with `System.arraycopy` if you indeed want to keep most of the original items:

```
String[] arr = new String[initialList.size()];
String[] src = initialList.toArray(new String[initialList.size()]);
int dstIndex = 0, blockStartIdx=0, blockSize=0;
for (int currIdx=0; currIdx < initialList.size(); currIdx++) {
    String item = src[currIdx];
    if (item.length() <= 4) {
        if (blockSize > 0)
            System.arraycopy(src, blockStartIdx, arr, dstIndex, blockSize);
            dstIndex += blockSize;
            blockSize = 0;
        } else {
            if (blockSize == 0)
                blockStartIdx = currIdx;
            blockSize++;
        }
    }
    ArrayList newList = new ArrayList(arr.length + 1);
    newList.addAll(Arrays.asList(arr));
}
```

It seems to be about 20% faster than your option 3.  Even more so (40%) if you can skip the new ArrayList creation at the end.

See: http://pastebin.com/sDhV8BUL

Comment: I am optimizing, and it's not premature. I'm not looking for the easiest thing to write, but for performance. Regarding Collection, I have an ArrayList to filter, can the Collection be created from the ArrayList (with no or little performance overhead compared to ArrayList copy) ?

Comment: In that case I'd recommend using a profiler to measure the difference in the real application.  That's the best way to get accurate data of the performance.

My favourite profiler is YourKit (http://www.yourkit.com/), but any decent profiler should be able to give you some estimates about the bottlenecks.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to go with the creating a new list from the initial one and removing. They would be less method calls that way since you're keeping ~80% of the original items.

Other than that, I don't know of any way to filter the items.

Edit: Apparently Google Collections has [something](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122105/java-what-is-the-best-way-to-filter-a-collection) that might interest you?

Comment: that can go up to O(n*(n*0.2)) time complexity (you need you shift the entire list when you remove the first element)

Comment: Google Collections +1, but removing items is bad idea as mentioned below: it will fail with ConcurrentModificationException.

Comment: @plouh it actually works (removing items is currently used), I don't understand why it would fail (with ArrayList) ?

Comment: It won't throw a ConcurrentModificationException because you're not modifying the same Collection, you're modifying a deep copy. It's not a reference to the original.

Comment: I seem to have missed the fact that he's iterating and removing from itself. He should be iterating over the original and removing from the copy or vice versa. ratchet is right.

Comment: My results say that it's best to create a new empty list (see my answer).

Comment: I did modify your benchmark with adding 5th option and randomizing the order of the items in the initial list and shaved some 20% off from the empty list option, if you have the memory to spare.  See my answher and pastebin for more details.

Answer (score 1):

As @Sanjay says, "when in doubt, measure".  But creating an empty ArrayList and then adding items to it is the most natural implementation and your first goal should be to write clear, understandable code.  And I'm 99.9% sure it will be the faster one too.

Update: By copying the old List to a new one and then striking out the elements you don't want, you incur the cost of element removal.  The ArrayList.remove() method needs to iterate up to the end of the array on each removal, copying each reference down a position in the list.  This almost certainly will be more expensive than simply creating a new ArrayList and adding elements to it.

Note: Be sure to allocate the new ArrayList to an initial capacity set to the size of the old List to avoid reallocation costs.

Comment: I'm working on optimization, I'm not looking for the clearest code actually.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's also the faster approach.

Answer (score 0):

I'd first follow the age old advice; when in doubt, measure.

> Should I use anything else than
>   ArrayList ?

That depends on what kind of operations would you be performing on the filtered list but ArrayList is usually is a good bet unless you are doing something which really *shouldn't* be backed by a contiguous list of elements (i.e. arrays).

> List newList = new
>   ArrayList(initialList.size());

I don't mean to nitpick, but if your new list won't exceed 80% of the initial size, why not fine tune the initial capacity to `((int)(initialList.size() * .8) + 1)`?

Comment: Checking the source code for the JDK 1.6 core I found that initializing the ArrayList with the exact capacity needed will trigger am increasing in capacity when the last element is added. Adding one to the initial capacity needed will solve this.

Comment: @soronthar: It was more of an example but nice catch. Fixed. :-)

Comment: I indeed mesured the difference and posted it as an answer

Answer (score 0):

the second is faster (iterate and add to second as needed) and the code for the first will throw ConcurrentModificationException when you remove any items

and in terms of what result type will be depends on what you are going to need the filtered list for

Comment: It shouldn't throw an exception if it's a new Collection. It'll throw the exception if that were a reference though.

Comment: Why would I get an exception? The current code is using the 1st form (deleting elements) and there is no exception.

Comment: @alex in the first code snippet he posted he iterates over the new  collection and removes from the same one

Comment: I see, you're absolutely right, I missed that. It would work correctly if he iterated over the original but removed from the copy though.

Comment: @alex Sorry I mistyped : the actual code is actually iterating over the original collection, I'll update the question.