# Java integer ArrayList return elements within a specific range

Tags: java, search, filter, arraylist

I am having a java ArrayList of integer

```
ArrayList <Integer> ageList  = new ArrayList <Integer>();
```

I am having some integer values in this arrayList. I want to create a new ArrayList which has all elements in the above arrayList which passes a condition, like value between 25 and 35. ie if my ageList contains values

> {12,234,45,33,28,56,27}

my newList should contain

> {33,28,27}

How can I achieve this?

Note: I came to java from objective C background, where I used NSPredicate to easly do such kind of things..Any similiar methods in java?

Comment: Just going over the list in a loop won't do?

Comment: Surely it will do, but I am already a loop of around 100 iteration, and I have to do the above inside that loop..Also I am asking for a faster way

Comment: I think you're making a big assumption; the ObjectiveC implementation will also loop over it, just you won't see the loop as it is masked by a feature.  The underlying implementation of NSPredicate will still have to loop over the array to assess each element.

Comment: I just hope that you are aware that with the toolkits mentioned below (specifically lambdaj) there is a performance hit relative to just iterating over... from what I know, at least.

Comment: Down voter please care to comment, so that I can understand what I did wrong..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no "filter" facility in the standard API. (There is in [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/google-collections/) and [Apache Commons](http://commons.apache.org/) however.) You'll have to create a new list, loop through the original list and manually add the elements in range 25-35 to the new list.

If you have no intention to keep the original list, you could remove the elements out of range using an `Iterator` and the `Iterator.remove` method.

If you have no duplicates in your list, you could use a `TreeSet` in which case you could get all elements in a specific range using `headSet` / `tailSet`.

**Related question:** (possibly even a duplicate actually)

- [What is the best way to filter a Java Collection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122105/java-what-is-the-best-way-to-filter-a-collection)

Comment: I wish there was a variant of the `foreach` loop that supported remove.

Comment: Well I saw that thread..And tried its implementation..I am one month into java, and I am understanding java as a pretty highlevel language..So I thought there should be some kind of pretty straightforward method..Also I am writing for Android, which is after all an embedded device, and one less line of code (especially in a loop) will do no harm..Anyway if I have to loop, I am ready to loop...Thanks for the effort..

Comment: Well I decided to loop around atlast..Dont want to add external libraries just for this case, even if it is by mighty Google..Thanks for the response..I am going to have a loooooooooooooooop......

Comment: you can also explore Navigable Set (unique values) and Navigable Map (key as unqiues values, value as count of duplicates) and then do headset, heapMap, tailSet, tailMap et-all

Answer (score 6):

Well, with [Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com) you could write:

```
Iterable<Integer> filtered = Iterables.filter(list, new Predicate<Integer>() {
    @Override public boolean apply(Integer value) {
        return value >= 25 && value <= 35;
    }
});
List<Integer> newList = Lists.newArrayList(filtered);
```

Comment: +1, nice. I usually write such ranges as `25 <= value && value <= 35` to mimic the mathematical notation `25 <= value <= 35`.

Comment: @aioobe: I appreciate that approach, but equally I find conditions with the constant on the left harder to understand. There's an argument for a range type in there somewhere :)

Comment: +1, if you can trust Guava doesn't phone home with each iteration. XD

Comment: Thanks for this, I never heard of Guava before, but I am only starting in java..For the present problem I decided to stick with a Iterator and loop..I am sure I will come back to guava sometime in future..

Answer (score 6):

You may use foreach loop

```
List<Integer> newList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for (Integer value : ageList) {
    if (value >= 25 && value <= 35) {
        newList.add(value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
ArrayList<Integer> newList = new ArrayList<Integer>(ageList);
for (Iterator<Integer> it = newList.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
    int n = it.next();
    if (n < 25 || n > 35)
      it.remove();
}
```

Comment: Will it deletes the original array with it.remove()?

Comment: It  will only delete elements in `newList`, not in the original `ageList`, as `it` is the iterator of `newList`.

Answer (score 1):

No there is no built in functionality in java [AFAIK].

The steps can be:

1. Loop through ageList.
2. Check for condition.
3. If condition is success then add that element to new list or else do nothing.

Sample code:

```
    List<Integer> ageList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    //-- add data in ageList

    List<Integer> newList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (Integer integer : ageList) {
        if(integer >= 25 && integer <= 35)
            newList.add(integer);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Not possible with the standard JCF. You'll have to iterate.

Consider using Guava. It has such kind of utilities.

http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over it and just add the ones that match?  It's 3 lines of code... 4 including the new ArrayList declration.