# querying in-memory collection

Tags: java, collections

I have a collection, a List of Map, the map is `Map<String, String>`. I need to query this collection with comparison, logical, like, not in operators. Something like SQL.

I will be populating the list from a database stored procedure, so I am not sure about the size. But, I guess the size should not be more than 10,000 records.

While posting this I am having a look at Apache functors, I don't know if they will help here.

Other way that I am thinking of is using the in-memory database Derby to achieve this.

Please let me know of any Java library or any other way of doing this.

The maps in the list will be like below:

```
Map<String, String> m1 = new Map<String, String>();
m1.put("name","Mark");
m1.put("age","21");
m1.put("city","some city");

Map<String, String> m1 = new Map<String, String>();
m1.put("name","David");
m1.put("age","25");
m1.put("city","other city");
```

I need to query the list to get Map which has:

1. `name=Mark`
2. `name=Mark and age > 30`
3. `city not in "other city"`

Comment: Define "better". Also, what is the size of the collection, and how frequently do you need to query it?

Comment: I am still not fully clear on what you want to do. Perhaps a few examples might be in order?

Comment: @aix The collection will be created & queried per request.

Comment: @thkala thanks.. updated my question with example

Comment: take a look [lambdaj](http://code.google.com/p/lambdaj/)

Comment: I don't understand the design. If the collections are created and queried (and destroyed?) with every request, then why not do all your filtering at the point where you are reading the data and creating the collections? Why store all the data and then query?

Comment: @theglauber The stored procedures that I get data from, I don't have control over them. The only thing I can use the stored procedures is to get data, rest all the data massaging has to be done at java side.

Comment: It looks like you're creating your collections from what the stored procedures return, i.e. the SPs are returning something else (ResultSet?) that you then use to create the collections. If you're querying those collections only once, you should be able to inspect what the SPs are returning, and if it doesn't satisfy your query, discard it and move to the next record. But if you are making more than one query per data set, then it makes sense to store everything and query the collections. You may be able to simplify your task through designing collections that support your queries well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found [JFilter](http://code.google.com/p/jfilter/) which helps you with filtering in-memory data (java objects ). Below is the description from JFilter website.

JFilter is a simple and high performance open source library to filter (query), map (select) and reduce (aggregate) objects in a Java collection. Query is given in json format like Mongodb queries.

I have written a [post](http://blogsbyabdullah.blogspot.in/2012/07/queryingfiltering-in-memory-data-using.html) on using [JFilter](http://code.google.com/p/jfilter/) with Maps, which I am using as a generic way of storing data and querying/filtering using [JFilter](http://code.google.com/p/jfilter/)

Here is the link to the post Using [JFilter to query/filter in-memory data](http://blogsbyabdullah.blogspot.in/2012/07/queryingfiltering-in-memory-data-using.html)

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [CQEngine - Collection Query Engine](http://code.google.com/p/cqengine/).

I'm biased as the author, but this will outperform and scale better than approaches which rely on iterating and filtering.

It provides an implementation of `java.util.Set` (IndexedCollection) which allows objects to be retrieved based on (arbitrarily complex) queries on their attributes.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Google Collections/Gauva](http://code.google.com/p/google-collections/). It provides collection filtering with predicates as :

> Iterables.filter(Iterable, Predicate)

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/122207/119772) for an example of filtering using predicates.

Comment: or [Functional Java](http://functionaljava.org/) or [Jedi](http://jedi.codehaus.org/) or someone else already mentioned LambdaJ.

Answer (score 0):

[Quaere](http://xircles.codehaus.org/projects/quaere) can query collections. You should have a look before going for an in-memory db based solution.