# manipulating arrays and vectors

Tags: java

I have code here that takes each `int` in `vecArray` and tries to determine if it is a prime number through a series of for loops. However when I run the program, I'm not able to successfully find/add each prime of the given array to the provided vector. What am I missing?

```
Vector<Integer> primeVec = new Vector<Integer>();
Vector<Integer> storage = new Vector<Integer>();
for ( int num : vecArray)  {
    //create array size of num
    resultArray = new int[num];
    for(int j = 1; j <= sqrt(num); j++)  {
        int result = num % j;
        if (result == 0)  {
             storage.add(j);
        }
    }
    //if resultArray has only two integers, then it must be prime
    int size = storage.size();
    if (size == 2)  {
       //add each 
       primeVec.add(num);
        System.out.println("You added " + num + " to the Vector for primes!");

    } 
    //print out all primes in vec
    for (int e = 0; e < primeVec.size(); e++)  {
     System.out.println("The prime in element number " + e + " is: " + primeVec.get(e));
    }
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: All numbers can be divided by 1. you should start your for loop at 2.

Comment: Even if your code works, I think you should take a look at this related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/122105/java-what-is-the-best-way-to-filter-a-collection to make your code more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code will try dividing by `1` two times, so the `resultArray.length` will be at least three.

You should start your loop at `j = 1` instead of `j = 0`, and replace `resultArray` with a `vector<int>`.

Note that factorization is not the fastest way to determine if the number is prime. You do not need to *store* the prime factors in order to count them. In addition, once you decided that a number is composite, you can end the loop. Finally, you do not need to try all divisors up to `num`: if you try divisors up to `sqrt(num)` and none of them divides `num`, then you know with certainty that the `num` is prime.

Comment: the resultArray in the j for loop?

Comment: @Jay Yes, if you would like to continue along the factorization route, you should replace the `resultArray` in the `j` loop with a vector that can grow.

Comment: hmmm i'm still not getting the results that i need

Comment: @Jay You may want to post an update to your question then to show what you have after the fix.

Comment: here's what i have changed it to

Comment: @Jay You have several problems in your new code: since you stop at `sqrt` (which should be `Math.sqrt`) prime numbers will produce the count of `1`, not `2`, because you do not go all the way to the `num` which is the second divisor. Also you should either clear the `storage` before the `for j` loop, or move its declaration inside the array. Here is [a link to ideone with your fixed program](http://ideone.com/VM8T7z).