# Java analogue of Python's filter()?

Tags: java, python

Is there any Java method that does exactly the same thing as Pyton's [filter()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html)? If so, which library is it in?

Comment: Check out [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/122105/1343161), it should help you.

Comment: @Keppil Yes yes yes it did! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's coming in Java 8. For the moment, your best bet is to use the Guava library, which has an [`Iterables.filter()`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html#filter%28java.lang.Iterable,%20com.google.common.base.Predicate%29) (or [`FluentIterable.filter()`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/FluentIterable.html#filter%28com.google.common.base.Predicate%29)) method.