# Return sublist of a List of object array

Tags: java

I'm getting result as below after making query to database

```
VendorName | IncidentID | IncidentStatus | IncidentDate
-------------------------------------------------------
XYZ        | 100        |     Open       | 02-JUN-2011    
ABC        | 101        |     Closed     | 03-JUN-2011  
MNP        | 102        |     Open       | 01-JUN-2011  
LPQ        | 103        |     Open       | 01-APR-2011
```

I'm iterating the list using following snippet of code

```
Iterator iter=resultList.iterator();
  while (iter.hasNext()) {
    Object[] result= (Object[]) iter.next();
    System.out.println("Vendor Name-->" +result[0]);
}
```

While iterating the list, I want to return only the Closed incident row. How to do this ?

I understand, it can be done by defining a new list and add one by one object to this but is there any better approach?

Comment: Aren't you getting a `ResultSet` object from the DB?

Comment: I would add the "only Closed" condition to the where clause in my database query, so you don't have to filter it yourself.

Comment: @rgettman I need to get the all the data and in certain scenario, i need to have this logic.

Comment: @Junaid I'm using JPA api Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery(queryString);List<T> resultList = query.getResultList(); I don't get ResultSet.

Comment: consider upvoting answers xD

Answer (score 0):

Why are you filtering the result set? It seems kinda unnecessary Why not just add "IncidentStatus == Closed" to your query?

Comment: I need to get the all the data and in certain scenario, i need to have this logic

Answer (score 0):

Here is a suggestion if you can't add the `where IncidentStatus=closed` to the sql.

```
//assume that Obj is one objet with the properties for this row
ArrayList<Obj> ret = new ArrayList<Obj>();
Iterator iter=resultList.iterator();
  while (iter.hasNext()) {
    Object[] result= (Object[]) iter.next();
    //check if the status is closed
    if(result[2].equals("Closed"){
         ret.add(new Obj(result[0],result[1],result[2],result[3]));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, first if it's posible it seems better to add the restriction when you query the database, otherwise I suggest you to use [Apache Commons Collection FilterIterator](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections/iterators/FilterIterator.html)

```
Predicate<Object[]> predicate = new Predicate<>() {
                   evaluate(Object[] obj) { 
                         return (obj[2].equals("Closed")); 
                   }
               };

Iterator<Object[]> filteredIterator = new FilterIterator<>(
                            resultList.iterator, 
                            predicate
                        );
```

This aproach allows you to create a generic table predicate class that helps you filter an iterator or a collection using any field and value.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using java 1.7

```
if(resultList == null)
  return;

List<MyClass> toReturn = new ArrayList<>(resultList.size());

for(MyClass element : resultList){
  if (element.isClosedState()){
    toReturn.add(element);
  }
}
```

You can use external api.

[lambdaj](http://code.google.com/p/lambdaj/) allows to filter collections without writing loops or inner classes as in the following example:

```
List<MyClass> elements = select(element, having(on(MyClass.class).getProperty(),
    greaterThan(someValue)));
```

[guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) or wait `Java 8` release.

this link may help you [what is the best wat to filter a collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122105/java-what-is-the-best-way-to-filter-a-collection)