# how do I compare a input string “BBBB” with the schools in the above ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist

Let say I have an `ArrayList<Student>`  contains 4 `Students(name , city, school)`.
For example:

```
 1. John   Nevada   BBBB
 2. Mary   Ander    AAAA
 3. Winn   Arcata   CCCC
 4. Ty     Artes    BBBB
```

If user enter “BBBB” then it displays: :

```
 1. John    Nevada   BBBB
 2. Ty      Artes    BBBB
```

My question is that how do I compare a input string “BBBB” with the schools in the above `ArrayList`? 
Thank you for any help that you guys would provide!

```
public class Student
{
    private String name;
    private String city;
    private String school;

    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class Student
     */
    public Student(String name, String city, String school)
    {
       this.name = name;
       this.city = city;
       this.school = school;
    }

    public String getSchool(String school)
    {
        return this.school = school;
    }

     public String toString()
    {
        return  "Name: " + name + "\tCity: " +city+ "\tSchool: "+school;
    }


}


public class AllStudent
{
    // instance variables - replace the example below with your own
    private ArrayList<Student> listStudent = new ArrayList<Student>();

    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class AllStudent
     */
    public AllStudent() throws IOException
    {

        //variables
        // read an input file and save it as an Arraylist
        fileScan = new Scanner (new File("students.txt");
        while(fileScan.hasNext())
        {
            //.......
            listStudent.add(new Student(name,city,school);
     }
     //now let user enter a school, the display name, city, school of that student.
     //i am expecting something like below...
     public void displayStudentBasedOnSchool(String school)
     {
       for (i = 0; i < listStudent.size(); i++)
       {
        //what should i put i here to comapre in input School with school in the listStudent>
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: We would have to see your code; you likely just have to modify one thing (make something like a `searchByCity(String s)` function).

Comment: You may need to override `compare` method to define compare logic in Student class

Comment: Start by posting your `Student` class and how you declare and use your `ArrayList`.

Comment: How are you students stored? An object, a string of the format above? Are those numbers an index in the `ArrayList`? @captain I suspect I would recommend against that. Chances are that a Student's `compare` method shouldn't be based only on the school.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe `Student is class` and you are creating list of `Student`

The `ArrayList` uses the `equals` method implemented in the class (your case Student class) to do the equals comparison.

You can call contains methods of list to get matching object

Like,

```
public class Student {
  private String name;
  private String city;
  private String school;
  ....   

  public Student(String name, String city, String school) {
      this.name = name;
      this.city = city;
      this.school = school;
  }

   //getters & setters..
  public String setSchool(String school) {
      this.school = school;
  }

  public String getSchool() {
      return this.school;
  }

  public boolean equals(Object other) {
      if (other == null) return false;
      if (other == this) return true;

      if (!(other instanceof Student)) return false;
      Student s = (Student)other;

      if (s.getSchool().equals(this.getSchool())) {
          return true; // here you compare school name
      } 
      return false;
  }

  public String toString() {
      return  "Name: " + this.name + "\tCity: " + this.city + "\tSchool: "+ this.school;
  }
}
```

Your array list would be like this

```
ArrayList<Student> studentList = new ArrayList<Student>();  

Student s1 = new Student(x, y, z);
Student s2 = new Student(a, b, c);  

studentList.add(s1);
studentList.add(s2);

Student s3 = new Student(x, y, z); //object to search

if(studentList.contains(s3)) {
    System.out.println(s3.toString()); //print object if object exists;
} // check if `studentList` contains `student3` with city `y`.It will internally call your equals method to compare items in list.
```

Or,

You can simply iterate object in `studentList` and compare items

```
for(Student s : studentList) {
  if(s.getSchool().equals(schoolToSearch)) {
    // print object here!..

  }
}
```

Or, as you commented ,

```
public void displayStudentBasedOnSchool(String school){
    for(int i = 0; i < studentList.size(); ++i) {
        if(studentList.get(i).getSchool().equals(school)) {
            System.out.println(studentList.get(i).toString()); // here studentList.get(i) returns Student Object.
        }
    }
}
```

Or,

```
ListIterator<Student> listIterator = studentList.listIterator(); //use list Iterator

while(listIterator.hasNext()) {
    if(iterator.next().getSchool().equals(school)) {
        System.out.println(listIterator.next());
        break;
    }
}
```

or even,

```
int j = 0;
while (studentList.size() > j) {
    if(studentList.get(j).getSchool().equals(school)){
        System.out.println(studentList.get(j));
        break;
    }
    j++;
}
```

So now you have set of options

1. `for-loop`
2. `for-each` loop
3. `while` loop
4. `iterator`

Comment: yes, I have been working on your feedback. I tried to fix my code with your answer to match my need, but it still does not work.The error message was: "array required, but java.util.ArrayList<Student> found".

Comment: dont be sorry,that was what I figured too.I actually had came up with your last code before I posted this problem, but it still does not work. the error message was: "method getSchool in class Student cannot be applied to given types. require:java.lang.String; found: no arguments; reason: actual or formal argument lists differ in length.

Comment: public class Student
{
    private String name;
    private String city;
    private String school;

    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class Student
     */
    public Student(String name, String city, String school)
    {
       this.name = name;
       this.city = city;
       this.school = school;
    }
    
    public String getSchool(String school)
    {
        return this.school = school;
    }
    
     public String toString()
    {
        return  "Name: " + name + "\tCity: " +city+ "\tSchool: "+school;
    }
    

}

Comment: I still get the same error as I indicated above "mothod getSchool......". Thanks for being so helpfull.

Comment: I totally understand. Maybe I need to play around with it little more. I will let you know when it finally works.

Comment: AAAAAAAAAAA my program works perfectly now. I have learned a lot. Thank you so much guys, . you guys are amazing :D. Special thank you to CAPTAIN!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your student is modelled like this (AAAA, BBBB values are stored in `blah` field):

```
public class Student {

  private String name;
  private String state;
  private String blah;

  //getters & setters..

}
```

The simplest (not most efficient way) is just to loop the array list and compare the query string with value of blah field

```
for(Student s : studentList) {
  if(s.getBlah().equals(queryString)) {
    // match!..
  }
}
```

Comment: acctually, it is an arrayList

Comment: acctually, it is an arrayList of student, and each student has three parameter including name, city, school. for example if I loop throgh the arraylist 
    
    public void displayStudentBasedOnSchool(String BBBB)
    {
         for(int i  = 0; i < studentList.size(); i ++)
        {
           //how do i campare the input "BBBB" with parameter school in this studentList?
        }
        
      }

Comment: `for(Student s : studentList)` is an 'syntax sugar' for `for(int i=0; i < studentList.size(); i++) { Student s = studentList.get(i); ...`

Comment: can i use s.contains(comparedSchool)? after set it up each s = studentList.get(i)?

Comment: @gerrytan Strictly speaking, the `for`-each construct uses an iterator unless the collection is an array. (See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/85190/how-does-the-java-for-each-loop-work).) That means it works on any `Iterable` and will be reasonably efficient with other constructs like `LinkedList`.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably use [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) library from Google.
Take a look at this question: [What is the best way to filter a Java Collection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122105/java-what-is-the-best-way-to-filter-a-collection) It provides many excelent solutions for your problem.

Comment: Let him understand java's capability/features first.Its not preferred to switch over library for such a ant size code when java can do it