# MongoDB Java Driver

Tags: java, json, mongodb

Given some JSON value and a query in MongoDB format, I want to filter the same way that MongoDB does, the json entities I want without going to the MongoDB.

For example, I have:

JSON Value: [{qty: 10}, {qty: 30}, {qty: 50}]
Query in MongoDB format: { qty: { $gt: 20 } }

Result: [{qty: 50}]

I want that without going to Mongo database, for example calling some method that recives JSON Value and JSON Query String in Mongo format, inside some JAR.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> I want that without going to Mongo database

Parse JSON using [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) and create a `Query` Object and a `Collection` containing the target objects.

Use a collections framework such as Guava or GS-Collections and [filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122105/java-what-is-the-best-way-to-filter-a-collection).

Answer (score 0):

'Jackson' library offers JSON parsing & generation in Java. Once you've parsed, you can filter values/ data structure using Java code to your heart's content.

Java obviously has no direct implementation of Mongo query language.. you can implement Java code yourself as desired.

See:

- http://jackson.codehaus.org/