# Convert List of List into list in java

Tags: java, arraylist

```
List<List<String>> superlist = new ArrayList<List<String>>();

List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
list1.add("a1");
list1.add("a2");

List<String> list2 = new ArrayList<String>();
list2.add("b1");
list2.add("b2");

List<String> list3= new ArrayList<String>();
list3.add("c1");
list3.add("c2");

superlist.add(list1);
superlist.add(list2);
superlist.add(list3);

List<String> result= new ArrayList<>();
```

Now I want to create a new list which contains all the values in `superList`.
Here result should contain `a1,a2,b1,b2,c1,c2`

Comment: have you made an attempt at doing this on your own? a couple of foreach loops should do the job perfectly well.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25147094/turn-a-list-of-lists-into-a-list-using-lambdas

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Try like this using `flatMap`:

```
List<List<Object>> list = 
List<Object> lst = list.stream()
        .flatMap(Collection::stream)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 7):

If you're on Java < 8 (and cannot use `Stream`s), you can do this in a one-liner with Guava's [`Iterables.concat`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html#concat(java.lang.Iterable)):

```
List<String> merged = Lists.newArrayList(Iterables.concat(superList));
```

Answer (score 3):

```
superlist.forEach(e -> result.addAll(e));
```

Now after some reasarch, I found this way.

Comment: Which is the best method for the question in terms of performance

Comment: Actually, a plain for-loop would be even faster since iterators tend to consume quite a bit of memory if you use them all over the place. But most of the time performance is not even an issue, especially nowadays. I just noticed that this answer was posted almost 6 years ago.

Answer (score 2):

You would have to loop through every `List` in your `superlist` object in order to get all of the contents. You can use the `addAll()` method to copy each list's contents to your new `List`:

```
List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
for (List<String> list : superlist) {
    result.addAll(list);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me!

```
List<String> result= new ArrayList<>();
    
    superlist.stream().forEach(
            
            n->result.addAll(n)
            );
    
    System.out.println(result);
```