# How to change following nested FOR loops into Java8 Stream API?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

The following example may be trivial, but I have created it to show what I need to achieve using different data (not integers). This code is runnable etc.

```
List<List<Integer>> master = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    List<Integer> inner = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    master.add(inner);
    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
        inner.add(i * 10 + j);
    }
}
System.out.println(master);
//lets make single collections from that but add 1000 to every element - this represents some intermediate operations to generate part of final result
List<Integer> finalAccumulated = new ArrayList<Integer>(); // this will represent our accumulated, final result
for (List<Integer> topLvl : master) {
    ArrayList<Integer> intermedialeAccumulated = new ArrayList<>(); //this step is important as it represents returning a collection of results for stream#map not single result
    for (Integer nested : topLvl) { // this represents stream#map (or maybe collector?)
        intermedialeAccumulated.add(nested + 1000);
    }
    finalAccumulated.addAll(intermedialeAccumulated); // this represent accumulation of collection of results, not just single result like stream#map do
}
System.out.println(finalAccumulated);
```

How to get the same result as in `finalAccumulated` using **single** `Stream`. By single I mean that in call chain there can be **only single terminate action** so the resulting form would be

```
finalAccumulated=master.stream()...intermediateCalls()...terminateCollectingCall();
```

Online ide with running code [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_java8_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMY0FnQmU4Q2g5dkE)

Comment: `flatMap`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25147094/turn-a-list-of-lists-into-a-list-using-lambdas. Where are you stuck?

Comment: @Tunaki you are right, flatMap is the way to go. Simply speaking there is no other way then create some intermediate streams. I was curious if this can be avoided. Thank you again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a flat map:

```
List<Integer> finalAccumulated = master
  .stream()
  .flatMap((x) -> x.stream())
  .map((i) -> i + 1000)
  .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: The parenthesis around `x` and `i` aren't necessary. They actually add some overhead when reading. You can even write `.flatMap(List::stream)` to avoid using intermediate variables.

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire I'm pretty sure that the intermediate variable will get allocated anyway, even if you just pass the method reference around. In the end it is calling an interface method with this parameter, so you won't save the allocation.

Comment: Sorry, I should have said "declaring" instead of "using". That's what I actually meant. Because you don't declare it, it's already done.

Comment: If you won’t go that deep into detail, using the method reference `List::stream` does not only save a local variable, but an entire method stack frame. But for most use cases, it’s just an unimportant detail, as @Olivier Grégoire already pointed out, with a method reference, you save a *declaration*, i.e. don’t have to introduce a new identifier.

Answer (score -1):

Here's how to produce the same `finalAccumulated` using a single `Stream`

```
List<Integer> finalAccumulated = IntStream.range(1000, 1000 + 10 * 10).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Here would be an over-engineered and generic approach for such an operation

```
private static <T> List<T> flattenWith(List<List<T>> master, Function<T, T> transform) {
        return master.stream()
                     .flatMap(List::stream)
                     .map(transform)
                     .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
```

Usage

```
flattenWith(master, x -> x + 1000)
```

Comment: Doesn't start from `master`, althought it produces the same result, but for the example code only.

Comment: @Tunaki exactly. I need more generic code.

Comment: @Tunaki I know, I just wanted to point out that the question was a bit vague and could lead to such answer (that matches what is asked but not the way one would expect it).

Comment: The question is quite clear in that it is only an example. It's like answering "How to print the first 3 prime numbers" with `System.out.println("2, 3, 5")` and leaving everyone to wonder how to print the first 100.

Comment: @Antoniossss I've added a more generic example

Comment: @Spotted iv ended up using `list.parallelStream().map(mappingFunction).flatMap(MappingFunctionReturnType::stream).collect(Collectors.toList)` and this is exaclty what i needed thus this uses multiple intermediate streams i guess but there is no oway to do it on single stream. Thanks for the effort.

Answer (score -1):

```
 private static void test() {
        List<List<Integer>> master = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            List<Integer> inner = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            master.add(inner);
            for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
                inner.add(i * 10 + j);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(master);
//lets make single collections from that but add 1000 to every element - this represents some intermediate operations to generate part of final result
        List<Integer> finalAccumulated = new ArrayList<Integer>(); // this will represent our accumulated, final result
        for (List<Integer> topLvl : master) {
            ArrayList<Integer> intermedialeAccumulated = new ArrayList<>(); //this step is important as it represents returning a collection of results for stream#map not single result
            for (Integer nested : topLvl) { // this represents stream#map (or maybe collector?)
                intermedialeAccumulated.add(nested + 1000);
            }
            finalAccumulated.addAll(intermedialeAccumulated); // this represent accumulation of collection of results, not just single result like stream#map do
        }
        //map then using flatmap
        List<Integer> finalAccumulated2 = master.stream().map(topLvl -> {
            ArrayList<Integer> intermedialeAccumulated = new ArrayList<>();
            for (Integer nested : topLvl) { 
                intermedialeAccumulated.add(nested + 1000);
            }
            return intermedialeAccumulated;
        }).flatMap(intermedialeAccumulated -> intermedialeAccumulated.stream())
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
```