# java 8 collect List<String>

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, collectors

I am collecting String in List using Java 8.
But, this is giving me compile error that

> incompatible types: inference variable T has incompatible bounds
>       equality constraints: String
>       lower bounds: Object

```
final List<ProjectLevel> levels = projectLevelFacade
                    .findUUIDByNameorNumber(freeText, businessAccountId);
final List<String> uuids = levels
                    .stream()
                    .map((level) -> level.getProjectLevelsUUIDs()) // this return List<String>
                    .flatMap(Collection::stream)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

can any one have idea how to achieve this using Java 8?

Is there any type of casting or something for this?

I have also taken [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25147094/turn-a-list-of-lists-into-a-list-using-lambdas) from here.

Comment: Is `ProjectLevel` a generic? Should it be `ProjectLevel<?>` otherwise `getProjectLevelsUUIDs()` won't be generic either.

Comment: @PeterLawrey yes it's `ProjectLevel<?>`

Comment: @PavneetSingh it shouldn't work as error droves me somewhere else. still let me try

Comment: @PavneetSingh changed to `List::stream`.  same error!

Comment: @PavneetSingh, I don’t think that makes any difference.

Comment: I think you’d better provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: When you treat a class with generic types as a raw type, all it's methods and return values become raw types even if they didn't use the generic parameter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ProjectLevel` is a generic class - when you write `List<ProjectLevel>` you are using a raw type and the type inference system does not work any longer.

Try:

```
final List<ProjectLevel<?>> levels = projectLevelFacade
                .findUUIDByNameorNumber(freeText, businessAccountId);
```

and it should compile as expected.

Comment: it worked! but the problem arising now is from namedQuery it returns no generic. Means it returns `List<ProjectLevel>`. so not able to return it in `List<ProjectLevel<?>>`

Comment: @Hiru then you need to change that method too.

Comment: yes i tried this but in named query i am not able to `getResultList()` in `List<ProjectLevel<?>>`

Comment: I think i would have to ask separate question for this

Comment: @Hiru probably easier indeed

Comment: posted another thread. If you have any idea please suggest me

Comment: I had a look but I don't use JPA so not sure how to fix your problem.