# How to get a List of lists using Streams in this specific case?

Tags: java, list, java-8, java-stream, grouping

I have some classes like below:

```
Class A {
    private String name;
    private List<B> b;
    // getters and setters
}
Class B {
    private String name;
    private List<C> c;
    // getters and setters
}
Class C {
    private String name;
    private List<D> d;
    // getters and setters
}
Class D {
    // properties
    // getters and setters
}
```

Now I have a list of type `A`. What I want to do is to get a list containing other lists of type `D` like this:

```
List<List<D>>
```

I have tried somthing like this using `flatMap`:

```
listA.stream()
     .flatMap(s -> s.getB.stream())
     .flatMap(s -> s.getC.stream())
     .flatMap(s -> s.getD.stream())
     .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

But this collects all the elements of type `D` into a list:

```
List<D>
```

Can someone help please?

Comment: You can use flatMap to flatten the internal lists (after converting them to Streams) into a single Stream, and then collect the result into a list

Comment: Check here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25147094/how-can-i-turn-a-list-of-lists-into-a-list-in-java-8?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want a `List<List<D>>` you need one less `flatMap`:

```
List<List<D>> ds = listA.stream() // creates Stream<A>
                        .flatMap(s -> s.getB().stream()) // creates Stream<B>
                        .flatMap(s -> s.getC().stream()) // creates Stream<C>
                        .map(s -> s.getD()) // creates Stream<List<D>>
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

or

```
List<List<D>> ds = listA.stream() // creates Stream<A>
                        .flatMap(s -> s.getB().stream()) // creates Stream<B>
                        .flatMap(s -> s.getC().stream()) // creates Stream<C>
                        .map(C::getD) // creates Stream<List<D>>
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: FYI you can do the whole thing using only method references.

Comment: @Bohemian I know, but it would require more operations (splitting each `flatMap` to `map` + `flatMap`)

Comment: @Eran: Just a personal question... do you do anything else than answer all the Java-stream questions? xD

Comment: @Nikolas sometimes I answer non Java-stream questions :)