# List of lists and Java 8

Tags: java-8, java-stream

I have a list of class R with list of other class P

```
List<R> rList = getRListFromDb();
```

I would like to get the all the P objects in another list

```
List<P> result = new ArrayList<>();
```

I tried these, but giving me Class cast exception, saying class P cannot be converted to class R. By the way I have seen issue given below, but tried and could not figure it out.

[How can I turn a List of Lists into a List in Java 8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25147094/how-can-i-turn-a-list-of-lists-into-a-list-in-java-8)

```
1. rList.stream().map(R::getP).flatMap(List::stream).forEach(result::addAll);
2. rList.forEach(r -> result.addAll(r.getP()));
```

I would like to what is incorrect here and also would like to know different ways of getting this done in Java 8.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I turn a List of Lists into a List in Java 8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25147094/how-can-i-turn-a-list-of-lists-into-a-list-in-java-8)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
rList.stream().map(R::getP).flatMap(List::stream).forEach(result::addAll);
```

would work if you didn't use `flatMap` (since `addAll` requires a `Collection`, but `flatMap` transforms your `Stream<List<P>>` to a `Stream<P>`.

This would work:

```
rList.stream().map(R::getP).forEach(result::addAll);
```

With `flatMap` it should be:

```
rList.stream().map(R::getP).flatMap(List::stream).forEach(result::add);
```

That said, the correct way is to use `collect`:

```
List<P> result = rList.stream()
                      .map(R::getP)
                      .flatMap(List::stream)
                      .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

or

```
List<P> result = rList.stream()
                      .flatMap(r -> r.getP().stream())
                      .collect(Collectors.toList());
```