# Convert Delimited String in List<String> to List<String>

Tags: java, lambda

Assume we have a `List<String>` with some values containing the delimiter `,`, how do we convert split and merge into a `List<String>` without the delimiter `,`?

**Input**: `[ "1,2", "3,4", "5" ]`

**Output**: `[ "1", "2", "3", "4", "5" ]`

---

**Imperative code**

```java
List<String> input = Arrays.asList("1,2", "3,4", "5");
List<String> output = new ArrayList<>();
for (String str : input) {
  for (String split : str.split(",")) {
    output.add(split);
  }
}
```

Comment: I think you may be looking for some flatMap

Comment: and what did you try?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert comma-separated String to ArrayList?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7488643/how-to-convert-comma-separated-string-to-arraylist) and then [How can I turn a List of Lists into a List in Java 8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25147094/how-can-i-turn-a-list-of-lists-into-a-list-in-java-8)

Comment: @Naman The first question is pretty similar but not exactly answering this question as the `.flatMap()`  is not mentioned in that question. The second one looks like a duplicate of this question without some sample input and output.

Comment: @RogerNg you wouldn't always find an answer in a single question, but if only you would have started with an attempt you might have reached the other. Notice, I'd mentioned two links for marking this as a duplicate. (Primary motive - "Make an attempt!")

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it with `Stream`s:

```
List<String> output = input.stream()
                           .flatMap(s -> Arrays.stream(s.split(",")))
                           .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

For example,

```
List<String> input = Arrays.asList("1,2", "3,4", "5" );
List<String> output = input.stream()
                           .flatMap(s -> Arrays.stream(s.split(",")))
                           .collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println (output);
```

will output

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it as follows:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> list = List.of("1,2", "3,4", "5");
        List<String> newList = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.forEach(s -> Arrays.stream(s.split(",")).forEach(newList::add));
        System.out.println(newList);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```