# Is my understanding of Java Stream.flatMap correct?

Tags: java, lambda, java-stream

I was trying to answer this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60527064/convert-delimited-string-in-liststring-to-liststring), but I did not because I don't understand Streams well enough. Please tell me if my explanation is correct or not.

**My answer :**

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class Temp {
    public static void main(String [] args){
        String [] input = {"1,2", "3,4", "5"};
        String [] expected = {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5"};

        String [] actual = Stream.of(input)
                .flatMap(s -> Arrays.stream(s.split(",")))
                .toArray(String [] :: new);

        //Testing - Runs only when assertions are enabled for your JVM. Set VM args = -ea for your IDE.
        assert Arrays.equals(actual, expected) : "Actual array does not match expected array!";
    }
}
```

**My explanation :**

1 - Take a stream of elements (Strings in this example) and pass one element at a time to `flatMap`.

QUESTION - *Is this actually one element at a time ?*

2 - `flatMap` takes a `Function` which converts an element into a `Stream`. In the example, the function takes a String ("1,2") and converts it into a stream of multiple Strings ("1", "2"). The stream of multiple strings is generated by Arrays.stream(an array) which we know takes an array and converts it into a stream. That array was generated by `s.split(",")`. All other elements are processed and put into this one stream.

QUESTION - *Does flatMap return one Stream for all elements in input array OR one Stream per element of input array ?*

3 - `toArray` takes elements in the single stream it got from `flatMap` and puts them into one array.

Comment: (1) Yes. (2) The `Function` returns one stream per element in the original stream, allowing `flatMap` to return one stream containing all the "flattened" elements. (3) Too broad a question; to really understand how streams work I suggest looking at the source code.

Comment: Try this - `String[] actual = Stream.of(input)
                .flatMap(s -> Arrays.stream(s.split(",")))
                .peek(System.out::println)
                .toArray(String[]::new);` and then compare with `String[] actual = Stream.of(input)
                .peek(System.out::println)
                .flatMap(s -> Arrays.stream(s.split(",")))
                .peek(System.out::println)
                .toArray(String[]::new);`. It would help you with a confirmation on your own.

Comment: Vague title. Rewrite to summarize your specific technical issue.

Comment: @Slaw - I updated the question to be more specific by removing the last question.

Comment: While it’s correct that the stream processes “one element at a time”, it’s nothing you should worry about. You have defined an operation *for each element*, the order of processing doesn’t matter.

Answer (score 1):

Predefined syntax of flat map is

```
<R> Stream<R> flatMap(Function<? super T, ? extends Stream<? extends R>> mapper)

where, R is the element type of the new stream.
Stream is an interface and T is the type 
of stream elements. mapper is a stateless function 
which is applied to each element and the function
returns the new stream.
```

so how flatMap works internally?

**It first applies the function returning another Optional to the object inside (if present) and then flattens the result before returning it, so you don’t have to do it yourself.**

internally its defined something like this

```
public static <T> Optional<T> flatten(Optional<Optional<T>> optional) {
    return optional.orElse(Optional.empty());
}
```

So in your case

```
String [] actual = Stream.of(input)
            .flatMap(s -> Arrays.stream(s.split(",")))
            .toArray(String [] :: new);

StreamofInput(input)  - taking input as collection
flatMap: adding map function
s-> Arrays.stream(s.split(","))- taking argument from your arrays individually which is represent by "s" , then converting your array which is splitted by "," and converting into stream.
toArray : converting you result into flat single array because its stateless so it will give you new collection.
```

for more you can visit [here](https://dzone.com/articles/understanding-flatmap)