# segregate duplicates and non duplicates from a list of objects based on property on multiple property in java 8

Tags: java, spring, java-8

I want to segregate duplicates and non duplicates from a list of objects based on property customerId and customerRegistration using java 8

> segregate meaning

if I have 3 record with same customerId and customerRegistration, first record should add into nonduplicate list and 2 nd 3 record should be add in to duplicate list.

I have below pojo class created hashcode and equals method based on customerId and customerRegistration.

```
public class Asset {

private String customerName;    
private int customerId;   
private String Type;   
private String customerRegistration;   
private int assetTagList;   
private String rso;    
private String active;   
private int billableUser;    
private int billableAsset;

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
    Asset asset = (Asset) o;
    return customerId == asset.customerId && Objects.equals(customerRegistration, asset.customerRegistration);
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(customerId, customerRegistration);
}
```

}

I have written below logic in java7 which will work fine ,is there any way I can write using stream(convert forloop logic in the below code to stream)?

```
public  Map<String ,List<Asset>> execute1() throws IOException {

    List<Asset> assetList=new ArrayList<>();
    Set<Asset> set=new HashSet<>();
    List<Asset> duplicateList=new ArrayList<>();
    List<Asset> nonDuplicateList=new ArrayList<>();
    Map<String ,List<Asset>> map = new HashMap<>();
    Asset asset1 = new Asset("French Customer1", 673, "Vehicle", "KNH 9009", 175, "FR", "Yes", 0, 0);
    Asset asset2 = new Asset("French Customer2", 673, "Vehicle", "KNH 9009", 175, "FR", "Yes", 0, 0);
    
    Asset asset3 = new Asset("French Customer3", 673, "Vehicle", null, 175, "FR", "Yes", 0, 0);
    Asset asset4= new Asset("French Customer4", 673, "Vehicle", null, 175, "FR", "Yes", 0, 0);
    Asset asset5= new Asset("French Customer4", 673, "Vehicle", null, 175, "FR", "Yes", 0, 0);
    
    Asset asset6 = new Asset("French Customer5", 674, "Vehicle", "KNH 9008", 175, "FR", "Yes", 0, 0);
    
    assetList.add(asset1); 
    assetList.add(asset2);
    assetList.add(asset3);
    assetList.add(asset4);
    assetList.add(asset5);
    assetList.add(asset6);


    for (Asset assetTemp:assetList){
        if(set.add(assetTemp)){
            nonDuplicateList.add(assetTemp);
        }
        else {
            duplicateList.add(assetTemp);
        }
    }

    map.put("duplicate",duplicateList);
    map.put("nonDuplicateList",nonDuplicateList);
    
    
   return map
}
```

expecting output like below(from input assetList which is defined in the above execute1 function)

> nonDuplicateList should have (asset1,asset3,asset6):

```
Asset asset1 = new Asset("French Customer1", 673, "Vehicle", "KNH 9009", 175, "FR", "Yes", 0, 0);
Asset asset3 = new Asset("French Customer3", 673, "Vehicle", null, 175, "FR", "Yes", 0, 0);
Asset asset6 = new Asset("French Customer5", 674, "Vehicle", "KNH 9008", 175, "FR", "Yes", 0, 0);
```

> duplicateList should have:(asset2,asset4,asset5)

```
Asset asset2 = new Asset("French Customer2", 673, "Vehicle", "KNH 9009", 175, "FR", "Yes", 0, 0);
Asset asset4= new Asset("French Customer4", 673, "Vehicle", null, 175, "FR", "Yes", 0, 0);
Asset asset5= new Asset("French Customer4", 673, "Vehicle", null, 175, "FR", "Yes", 0, 0);
```

Comment: Your example doesn't meet your discription, at least for the content of the `duplicateList` . I would expect the duplicate list to contain `asset1 & asset3` .

Comment: @basavaraddy Curious to know why the same `customerId` has multiple customer names associated to it?

Comment: @Eritrean edited my question 
nonDuplicateList should have asset1,asset3,asset6 and duplicateList should have asset2,asset4,asset5.As defined beginning of the question i want segregate the records for Example :if I have 3 record with same customerId and customerRegistration, first record should add into nonduplicate list and 2 nd 3 record should be add in to duplicate list.

Comment: @GauthamM its just an example i want identify the records  which has occurred more than once based on customer and customer Registration field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can group the elements depending on adding to your set returns true or false:

```
public  static Map<String ,List<Asset>> execute2() throws IOException {

    List<Asset> assetList=new ArrayList<>();
    Asset asset1 = new Asset("French Customer1", 673, "Vehicle", "KNH 9009", 175, "FR", "Yes", 0, 0);
    Asset asset2 = new Asset("French Customer2", 673, "Vehicle", "KNH 9009", 175, "FR", "Yes", 0, 0);

    Asset asset3 = new Asset("French Customer3", 673, "Vehicle", null, 175, "FR", "Yes", 0, 0);
    Asset asset4= new Asset("French Customer4", 673, "Vehicle", null, 175, "FR", "Yes", 0, 0);
    Asset asset5= new Asset("French Customer4", 673, "Vehicle", null, 175, "FR", "Yes", 0, 0);

    Asset asset6 = new Asset("French Customer5", 674, "Vehicle", "KNH 9008", 175, "FR", "Yes", 0, 0);

    assetList.add(asset1);
    assetList.add(asset2);
    assetList.add(asset3);
    assetList.add(asset4);
    assetList.add(asset5);
    assetList.add(asset6);

    Set<Asset> set=new HashSet<>();
    return assetList.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(x -> set.add(x) ? "nonDuplicateList" : "duplicate"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the same approach of using `Set<Asset> set` and collect it to a map using `partitioningBy` collector. Even though it would not cause much issue in the given example, **Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22755993/7804477) answer to know *why you shouldn't use a Collector to mutate an existing collection.***

```java
assetList.stream().collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(set::add));
```

This would return a map with `Boolean` key, where `true` would be non-duplicates.