# Joining "parallel" lists in a stream using collect()

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I'm having trouble with joining lists created in a "parallelStream()".
Here is the situation :

- I have a `List<Pair>` that contains pairs of "int" values
- From each of those pairs, I am generating a `List<Edge>` using a "parallelStream()"
- I want to collect & join these lists into a "merged" `List<Edge>`

What I'd like to do (and I expected it to work, following the last bullet point of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21526973/3369191)) is the following :

```
List<Edge> edges = pairs.parallelStream()
        .map(p -> align(p.first(), p.second()))
        .collect(ArrayList::new, List::add, List::addAll);
```

With `align()` doing CPU-intensive work (which is why I need to "parallelize" it in the first place) and returning a `List<Edge>`.

The use of `collect()` prevents me from compiling, giving the following error :

> Error: java: incompatible types: cannot infer type-variable(s) R,E (argument mismatch; invalid method reference incompatible types: ArrayList< Edge > cannot be converted to int)

Note that I did manage to make similar (but "uglier" imo) versions work, which confuses me even more:

**v1 :**

```
List<List<Edge>> collect = pairs.parallelStream()
        .map(p -> align(p.first(), p.second()))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
collect.forEach(l -> l.forEach(edges::add));
```

**v2 :**

```
List<Edge> edges = new ArrayList<>();
pairs.parallelStream()
        .map(p -> align(p.first(), p.second()))
        .collect(Collectors.toList()).forEach(edges::addAll);
```

Can someone help me with this? I would like to avoid giving up and using "v2" ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not 100% clear, but it looks like you probably want

```
List<Edge> edges = pairs.parallelStream()
    .flatMap(p -> align(p.first(), p.second()).stream())
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Agreed; although I prefer, in this case, to `.map(p -> align(p.first(), p.second())).flatMap(Collection::stream)` :)

Comment: My feeling is that if you're already writing an explicit lambda, you might as well fold the `.stream()` call in there; if you were using a method reference I might feel differently.

Comment: Well, I can understand that; however I somehow resent writing too much "lambda code", and therefore aim at keeping such code as minimal as possible. And yes, that's a feeling, too

Comment: Well, SO will never stop to amaze me, thanks a lot, it in fact seems to work.
I'll accept your answer when I'll be able to, in ~5min apparently, because you were too fast for SO itself :D.

Answer (score 3):

You can also fix this by replacing `List::add` with `List::addAll` as the second argument to `collect`:

```
List<Edge> edges = pairs.parallelStream()
        .map(p -> align(p.first(), p.second()))
        .collect(ArrayList::new, List::addAll, List::addAll);
```