# Is it wrong to add elements into a java list, with parallel stream?

Tags: java, java-stream

Is it better to use some of thread safe collections ? Scope of the question is only the generation and adding of elements into the list.

```java
public List<BankDetailsDTO> generateBankDetailsDTOs(int amount) {
    List<BankDetailsDTO> result = new ArrayList<>();
    IntStream.range(0, amount).parallel().forEach(index -> {
        result.add(new BankDetailsDTO(bankDetailsDTOCounter.getAndIncrement(),
            faker.company().name(),
            faker.finance().iban(),
            faker.finance().bic(),
            faker.finance().iban()));
        });
        return result;
    }
}
```

Update
Ok this was an bad idea.

```
    public List<BankDetailsDTO> generateBankDetailsDTOs(int amount) {
        List<BankDetailsDTO> result = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>());
        IntStream.range(0, amount).parallel().forEach(index -> {
            result.add(new BankDetailsDTO(bankDetailsDTOCounter.getAndIncrement(),
                    faker.company().name(),
                    faker.finance().iban(),
                    faker.finance().bic(),
                    faker.finance().iban()));
        });
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Short answer: yes, it is wrong.

Comment: Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2715983/concurrent-threads-adding-to-arraylist-at-same-time-what-happens) also.

Comment: Why `add`ing inside `forEach` when you can first `map` and then `forEach` or `collect`?

Comment: This is basically using an `IntStream` to mimic a `for` loop, and making the stream parallel would most likely hurt performance (uses the shared pool, no performance advantage unless there's a large amount of real work to be done). So there's more wrong with this code than just the thread-unsafety.

Comment: @M.S. can you show me an example.

Comment: @Tristate example of what?

Comment: @M.S. how to map -> forEach or collect

Comment: `IntStream.range(0, amount).parallel().map(index -> new BankDetailsDTO(...)).forEach(result::add);`

Comment: [There are may ways](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21526973/2711488) and only the one you've chosen, using `forEach` and `add` requires a thread-safe collection. Since this collection is not really a pre-existing collection but created right before the stream operation, there is no reason to use this non-idiomatic solution.