# How to use Collectors.toList for ArrayList?

Tags: android, arraylist, collections

[image]
I am trying to filter my array list by creating a separate variable that stores the top 3 values. However, getting error in collections. I am new to this so any help would be great!

```
public static ArrayList<exercise> exerciseDetail() {
            ArrayList<exercise> elist = new ArrayList<>();
            elist.add(new exercise("Bicycle Crunches", R.drawable.ic_launcher_background, "MEDIUM", "20 Reps or 1 Minute", "Beginner", "Bicycle crunches are a great way to target the rectus abdominis and the obliques in one easy exercise"));
            elist.add(new exercise("Leg Raises", R.drawable.ic_launcher_background, "MEDIUM", "20 Reps or 1 Minute", "Beginner", "Bicycle crunches are a great way to target the rectus abdominis and the obliques in one easy exercise"));
            elist.add(new exercise("Bridges", R.drawable.ic_launcher_background, "MEDIUM", "20 Reps or 1 Minute", "Beginner", "Bicycle crunches are a great way to target the rectus abdominis and the obliques in one easy exercise"));
            elist.add(new exercise("Burpees", R.drawable.ic_launcher_background, "MEDIUM", "20 Reps or 1 Minute", "Beginner", "Bicycle crunches are a great way to target the rectus abdominis and the obliques in one easy exercise"));
            elist.add(new exercise("Side Twists", R.drawable.ic_launcher_background, "MEDIUM", "20 Reps or 1 Minute", "Beginner", "Bicycle crunches are a great way to target the rectus abdominis and the obliques in one easy exercise"));
            elist.add(new exercise("Planks", R.drawable.ic_launcher_background, "MEDIUM", "20 Reps or 1 Minute", "Beginner", "Bicycle crunches are a great way to target the rectus abdominis and the obliques in one easy exercise"));
            elist.add(new exercise("Bicycle Crunches", R.drawable.ic_launcher_background, "MEDIUM", "20 Reps or 1 Minute", "Beginner", "Bicycle crunches are a great way to target the rectus abdominis and the obliques in one easy exercise"));
            elist.add(new exercise("Bicycle Crunches", R.drawable.ic_launcher_background, "MEDIUM", "20 Reps or 1 Minute", "Beginner", "Bicycle crunches are a great way to target the rectus abdominis and the obliques in one easy exercise"));
            elist.add(new exercise("Bicycle Crunches", R.drawable.ic_launcher_background, "MEDIUM", "20 Reps or 1 Minute", "Beginner", "Bicycle crunches are a great way to target the rectus abdominis and the obliques in one easy exercise"));
            elist.add(new exercise("Bicycle Crunches", R.drawable.ic_launcher_background, "MEDIUM", "20 Reps or 1 Minute", "Beginner", "Bicycle crunches are a great way to target the rectus abdominis and the obliques in one easy exercise"));
            elist.add(new exercise("Bicycle Crunches", R.drawable.ic_launcher_background, "MEDIUM", "20 Reps or 1 Minute", "Beginner", "Bicycle crunches are a great way to target the rectus abdominis and the obliques in one easy exercise"));
            elist.add(new exercise("Bicycle Crunches", R.drawable.ic_launcher_background, "MEDIUM", "20 Reps or 1 Minute", "Beginner", "Bicycle crunches are a great way to target the rectus abdominis and the obliques in one easy exercise"));
            elist.add(new exercise("Bicycle Crunches", R.drawable.ic_launcher_background, "MEDIUM", "20 Reps or 1 Minute", "Beginner", "Bicycle crunches are a great way to target the rectus abdominis and the obliques in one easy exercise"));
            elist.add(new exercise("Bicycle Crunches", R.drawable.ic_launcher_background, "MEDIUM", "20 Reps or 1 Minute", "Beginner", "Bicycle crunches are a great way to target the rectus abdominis and the obliques in one easy exercise"));
            elist.add(new exercise("Bicycle Crunches", R.drawable.ic_launcher_background, "MEDIUM", "20 Reps or 1 Minute", "Beginner", "Bicycle crunches are a great way to target the rectus abdominis and the obliques in one easy exercise"));
            elist.add(new exercise("Bicycle Crunches", R.drawable.ic_launcher_background, "MEDIUM", "20 Reps or 1 Minute", "Beginner", "Bicycle crunches are a great way to target the rectus abdominis and the obliques in one easy exercise"));
            elist.add(new exercise("Bicycle Crunches", R.drawable.ic_launcher_background, "MEDIUM", "20 Reps or 1 Minute", "Beginner", "Bicycle crunches are a great way to target the rectus abdominis and the obliques in one easy exercise"));
            elist.add(new exercise("Bicycle Crunches", R.drawable.ic_launcher_background, "MEDIUM", "20 Reps or 1 Minute", "Beginner", "Bicycle crunches are a great way to target the rectus abdominis and the obliques in one easy exercise"));
            elist.add(new exercise("Bicycle Crunches", R.drawable.ic_launcher_background, "MEDIUM", "20 Reps or 1 Minute", "Beginner", "Bicycle crunches are a great way to target the rectus abdominis and the obliques in one easy exercise"));
            return elist;



            ArrayList<exercise> filteredExercises = elist.stream().filter(item-> item.getName().equals("Bicycle Crunches") || item.getName().equals("Leg Raises")|| item.getName().equals("Bridges")).collect(Collectors.toList());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please don't tag questions with the android-studio tag just because you use it: the Android Studio tag should **only** be used when you have questions about the IDE itself, and not any code you write (or want to write) in it. See [when is it appropriate to remove an IDE tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/315196/6296561), [How do I avoid misusing tags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/354427/6296561), and [the tagging guide](/help/tagging). Use [android] or other relevant tags instead.

Answer (score 5):

`Collectors.toList()` will collect to a `List` of an intentionally unspecified type. As [its documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toList--) says:

> There are no guarantees on the type, mutability, serializability, or thread-safety of the `List` returned…

If you don’t need a specific `List` with guaranties regarding one of the mentioned traits, just change the declaration of you result variable to

```
List<exercise> filteredExercises = …
```

Otherwise, if you really need an `ArrayList`, use `Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new)` instead of `Collectors.toList()`.

See also [this exhaustive list of alternatives](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21526973/2711488).

---

As a side note, you should try to adhere to the standard naming conventions and use an uppercase letter for the start of your class names.