# Is There a method that finds first matched element with a condition In List In Java 8 like C# Enumerable#First and Scala List#find?

Tags: java, java-8

Like C# LINQ [Enumerable#First](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/bb535050%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) with delegate method
and Scala [List#find](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.collection.immutable.List) method, 
In Java8,
is there a method that finds first matched element with a condition in list?

Comment: Related: find all: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/122105/what-is-the-best-way-to-filter-a-java-collection

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
list.stream().filter(predicate).findFirst();
```

Comment: Thank you for your rapid answer.
And I'm sorry. My Quesition is so bad.
I knew it.
I want to know that 
Is there high order function to find element that matched condition.
Like C# Enumerable#First and Scala List#find with delegate or closure

Comment: ...I don't understand what about that question is not answered by this answer.  `filter` accepts a function you provide; it's higher-order.

Comment: Sorry my comment is so bad. Yes, you are right. Filter method accepts a funcition I provide. The way you told me is two methods chain, filter and findFirst. I want to know existing the way that add lambda and collect first matched element with one method.

Comment: Why does it matter that it's two methods instead of one?  The whole point of the API is to provide a few building blocks that you can stick together to do whatever you want; it'd be ridiculous to try to provide one method for each possible combination of operations.

Comment: I'm happy if I know that there is no way with one method. 
I want to know that does it exist or not.
So, In java-8, should we use two method combinations?
Is it java-8 calture or API designing?

Comment: There is no way with one method, which is a result of a deliberate tendency to prefer a minimal API that can still be combined to accomplish everything it needs to.

Comment: Oh, I understand!

> _result of a deliberate tendency to prefer a minimal API that can still be combined to accomplish everything it needs to._

Thank you so much.
I can understand the reason why there is no method like Enumerable#First[C#] in java from your comment.
Thenk you your nice comments!

Answer (score 6):

Yes, use [`Stream#findFirst()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#findFirst--) method:

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("a", "ab", "bc", "abc");
String firstMatch = list.stream().filter(s -> s.length() == 2).findFirst().get();
```

Comment: Thank you for your rapid answer and nice sample codes.
And I'm sorry. My Quesition is so bad.
I knew it.
I want to know that 
Is there high order function to find element that matched condition.
Like C# Enumerable#First and Scala List#find with delegate or closure

Comment: @muhron Can you clarify what you mean by high order function, if not what is being given in the answer already?

Comment: Sorry my comment is so bad.
Yes, you are right.
Filter method accepts a funcition I provide.
The way you told me is two methods chain, filter and findFirst.
I want to know existing the way that add lambda and collect first matched element with one method.

Comment: @muhron No there is no way to do this with one method. You might be able to create your own. But Java doesn't provide one.

Comment: Thank you.
I'm happy because I have just learned the method doesn't exist.
I wanted to know that does it exist or not.
So, different from C#, scala and groovy,
In java-8 we should use two method combinations? 
Is it true?
It is calture and API designing, ok?

Comment: @muhron Why do you insist on having a single method? The point is, a single method should do only a single thing. You can club the `filter` and `findFirst` methods into one, but then that will not be a very moduler design. Reusing the methods will not be possible. APIs are designed taking such things into consideration. Of course, they can't be pre-cooked according to the user's need.

Comment: With C# I use Enumerable#First with delegate many times.
And I want to know is exist like that method and how to write in Java8, single method or methods combination.
But now, from you and other person comments, I understand that java API designing is prefer a minimal API and they are combined.
So I understand that I should use two method combination in Java8.
I know that the word : When in Rome, do as the Romans do.
So I'll write that process with filter and findFirst combinations.
Thank you for your nice comments.