# how to check if all elements of java collection match some condition?

Tags: java, collections

I have an `ArrayList<Integer>`. I want to check if all elements of the list are greater then or less then certain condition. I can do it by iterating on each element. But I want to know if there is any method in Collection class to get the answer like we can do to find maximum or minimum with `Collections.max()` and `Collections.min()` respectively.

Comment: If i'm not wrong, Collections.max() and Collections.min() also iterate through each element.

Comment: `max` and `min` make no sense per se, because `Collection` is a generic type. for instance if you have `Collection<Object>`, what would be `max` and `min`? take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/122105/what-is-the-best-way-to-filter-a-java-collection

Answer (score 64, accepted):

If you have java 8, use stream's `allMatch` function ([reference](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/ma14-java-se-8-streams-2177646.html)):

```
 ArrayList<Integer> col = ...;
 col.stream().allMatch(i -> i>0); //for example all integers bigger than zero
```

Comment: Didn't know about this, seems useful! :D

Comment: very useful..something new to me..Thanks

Comment: I am not getting how to use this predicate and pass it in to argument. Can anyone give me demo ?

Comment: Still useful and saves lives four years later :D

Comment: Should probably be noted that the above solution will return true for an empty list.

Answer (score 8):

You can use Google guavas `Iterables.all`

```
 Iterables.all(collection, new Predicate() {
    boolean apply(T element)  {
       .... //check your condition 
   } 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot check values without iterating on all elements of the ***list***.

```
for(Integer value : myArrayList){

    if(value > MY_MIN_VALUE){
        // do my job
    }
}
```

I hope this will help

Comment: I want to do my job only if all elements of list > of my condition

Answer (score 0):

The answer `col.stream().allMatch` is the best solution for the original task, i.e. to check if all elements fulfill some condition.

If you instead want to find the min or max int value of a Stream/Collection you must first convert it to an `IntStream` using `col.stream().mapToInt(ToIntFunction)` where the ToIntFunction can be `MyObject::getIntvalue` or `o -> o.getIntValue()` or `Integer::intValue` if you already have a List<Integer> as explained on [How do I get an IntStream from a List<Integer>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24633913/how-do-i-get-an-intstream-from-a-listinteger)