# How do I get an IntStream from a List<Integer>?

Tags: java, collections, java-8, java-stream, boxing

I can think of two ways:

```
public static IntStream foo(List<Integer> list)
{
    return list.stream().mapToInt(Integer::valueOf);
}

public static IntStream bar(List<Integer> list)
{
    return list.stream().mapToInt(x -> x);
}
```

What is the idiomatic way? Maybe there is already a library function that does exactly what I want?

Comment: Another possible way could be to [use `flatMapToInt` along with `Instream.of`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53878820/1746118)

Comment: Using `Integer::valueOf` is hilariously inefficient. I wonder how often things like that occur in production code. I've seen the odd less egregious examples of boxing-unboxing.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

I guess (or at least it is an alternative) this way is more performant:

```
public static IntStream baz(List<Integer> list)
{
    return list.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue);
}
```

since the function [`Integer::intValue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#intValue--) is fully compatible with [`ToIntFunction`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/util/function/ToIntFunction.html) since it takes an `Integer` and it returns an `int`. No [autoboxing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html) is performed.

I was also looking for an equivalent of [`Function::identity`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html#identity--), i hoped to write an equivalent of your `bar` method :

```
public static IntStream qux(List<Integer> list)
{
    return list.stream().mapToInt(IntFunction::identity);
}
```

but they didn't provide this `identity` method. Don't know why.

Comment: lol, I confused `Integer::valueOf` with `Integer::intValue`. My proposed function `foo` unboxes the Integer in the list to pass it into `valueOf`, then it gets returned in a box, and then it is unboxed *again* to be put into the stream :)

Comment: Why would `Integer::intValue` be more performant than `x -> x`?

Comment: @shmosel because no autoboxing is performed by `intValue`

Comment: What autoboxing? In the lambda version, x is already an Integer (from the List), and "return x" implicitly _un_boxes it to an int, using intValue. I suspect that the difference would start out imperceptibly small, and get smaller by the time the JIT is through with it.

Comment: @yshavit not to mention that an identity function would do the exact same thing as well.

Comment: @yshavit the boxing that happens when the Integer value is passed to the applyAsInt() method which accepts an object reference and is returned as an int, then boxed back to Integer again to be a part of the IntStream, I guess.

Comment: @VictorZamanian - there is no boxing there. The value starts out as `Integer` in the list, and is passed to `ToIntFunction.applyAsInt(T value)`, which accepts an object and returns `int` so there is no boxing to convert `Integer` to `T` while calling that. Then the lambda function `x -> x` takes an `Integer x` and returns it, meaning it is unboxed to conform to the `int` return type. There is no futher boxing or unboxing. A valid reason to prefer `Integer::intValue` is that no additional lambda function is created - the method reference can be used directly.

Comment: @BeeOnRope, you're right -- I was thinking of `IntStream` as a stream of `Integer`, not of `int`. My mistake.

Comment: @gontard Do you want to say that explicit unboxing is faster than implicit?

Answer (score 7):

An alternate way to transform that would be using [`Stream.flatMapToInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMapToInt(java.util.function.Function)) and [`IntStream.of`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#of(int)) as:

```
public static IntStream foobar(List<Integer> list) {
    return list.stream().flatMapToInt(IntStream::of);
}
```

*Note*: Went through few linked questions before posting here and I just couldn't find this suggested in them either.

Comment: Clever. Hopelessly inefficient even for streams. But clever.