# Stream to IntStream in Java

Tags: java, lambda, java-stream

I have an ArrayList `list` with the values `90, 80, 75` in it that I want to convert to an IntStream. 
I have tried using the function `list.stream()`, but the issue I come upon is that when I attempt to use a lambda such as:
`list.stream().filter(x -> x >= 90).forEach(System.out.println(x);` 
 It will not let me perform the operations because it is a regular stream, not an IntStream. Basically what this line is supposed to do is that if the 90 is in the list to print it out.
What am I missing here? I can't figure out how to convert the Stream to an IntStream.

Comment: Maybe .map()?  (I don't use streams often, so...)

Comment: How is your `ArrayList` declared?

Comment: First example in the streams documentation uses `mapToInt` https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html

Comment: @tinstaafl ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();

Comment: Pertaining to the title, might just be little simpler - [`list.stream().flatMapToInt(IntStream::of)`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53878820/1746118)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `mapToInt` as

```
list.stream()
    .mapToInt(Integer::intValue)
    .filter(x -> x >= 90)
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: Thank you -- this is exactly what I was searching for.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the stream to an `IntStream` using `.mapToInt(Integer::intValue)`, but only if the stream has the type `Stream<Integer>`, which implies that your source list is a `List<Integer>`.

In that case, there is no reason why

```
list.stream().filter(x -> x >= 90).forEach(System.out::println);
```

shouldn’t work. It’s even unlikely that using an `IntStream` improves the performance for this specific task.

The reason why you original code doesn’t work, is that `.forEach(System.out.println(x);` isn’t syntactically correct. First, there is a missing closing brace. Second, `System.out.println(x)` is neither, a lambda expression nor a method reference. You have to use either,
 `.forEach(x -> System.out.println(x));`or `.forEach(System.out::println);`. In other words, the error is not connected to the fact that this is a generic `Stream` instead of an `IntStream`.