# How to filter the Set?

Tags: java, foreach, set

In the below code I am iterating set And here i need to get one object from the set where primary deparment is true and status is active how i can reduce the code to execute in  one step.

```
Set<EmployeeDeparment> dep = p.getRequestEmpId().getEmpdep();       
if (!dep.isEmpty()) {
    for (EmployeeDeparment employeeDeparment : dep) {
        if (employeeDeparment.isPrimarydept() == true && employeeDeparment.isStatus() == true) {
            System.out.println("inside the employeedep");
            leaveRequestForm.setApprovalauthority(employeeDeparment.getReportingTo().getFirstname() + "" + employeeDeparment.getReportingTo().getLastname());
        }
    }
} else {
     leaveRequestForm.setApprovalauthority("Approvalauthority not Configured");
}
```

Updated

```
List<EmployeeDeparment> beerDrinkers = select(persons, having(on(EmployeeDeparment.class).isPrimarydept(),
                        true));
```

This is giving compile time error.

Comment: Your question has been answered already - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/122105/what-is-the-best-way-to-filter-a-java-collection

Comment: List<EmployeeDeparment> beerDrinkers = select(persons, having(on(EmployeeDeparment.class).isPrimarydept(),
                        true)); I have written like this but i am getting exception as create on class

Comment: What version of Java are you using? Java 6, Java 7 or Java 8?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Guava's [Iterables.filter()](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html#filter(java.lang.Iterable,%20com.google.common.base.Predicate)) method.

You're predicate will be something like this:

```
Predicate<EmployeeDeparment> predicate = new Predicate<EmployeeDeparment>() {

public boolean apply(EmployeeDeparment employeeDeparment){
    return employeeDeparment.isPrimarydept() == true && employeeDeparment.isStatus() == true;
}
```

Your loop will then be:

```
for (EmployeeDeparment filteredEmployeeDeparment : Iterables.filter(dep, predicate)) {
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Set<EmployeeDeparment> dep = p.getRequestEmpId().getEmpdep();       
if (!dep.isEmpty()) 
{
    for (EmployeeDeparment employeeDeparment : dep) 
    {
       if (employeeDeparment.isPrimarydept() == true && employeeDeparment.isStatus() == true) 
       {
           System.out.println("inside the employeedep");
           leaveRequestForm.setApprovalauthority(employeeDeparment.getReportingTo().getFirstname() + "" + employeeDeparment.getReportingTo().getLastname());
       }
    }
}
else 
{
    leaveRequestForm.setApprovalauthority("Approvalauthority not Configured");
}
```

can be replaced by

```
Set<EmployeeDeparment> dep = p.getRequestEmpId().getEmpdep();       
if (!dep.isEmpty()) 
{
    dep.stream()
       .filter((employeeDeparment) -> employeeDeparment.isPrimarydept() == true && employeeDeparment.isStatus() == true)
       .forEach((x) -> 
       {
           System.out.println("inside the employeedep");
           leaveRequestForm.setApprovalauthority(employeeDeparment.getReportingTo().getFirstname() + "" + employeeDeparment.getReportingTo().getLastname());
       });
}
else
{
    leaveRequestForm.setApprovalauthority("Approvalauthority not Configured");
}
```

Comment: if anyone knows a better way of handling the two conditions though, I'm all ears!

Comment: the OP has the second part outside of the loop, as else to **"if (!dep.isEmpty())"**

Comment: @simo.3792095 thank you for the observation, K&R tends to mess me up -_- fixed and thanks again

Comment: You've made me look up K&R now. I was oblivious to the fact that each positioning of the open curly brace and indenting had a different style name (thanks wikipedia). That aside the original post didn't follow any of those particular styles, so that explains the confusion.

Comment: @simo.3792095 yeah it does, some of them are pretty weird. But I think Allman style with 4 space indent is the best, but at work I am forced to use k&r 2 space indent - it is so jarbled! The control keywords are over the statements and the whole thing is a mess, the opening braces are unpredictable, the code lacks structure, the blocks are non-existent. I really don't know why people still use it, as it makes debugging hell.

Comment: Or at least that is the way I personally see it. Especially since I have fixed programming errors in someone else's code by using the Auto-formatter before.