# OrderBy in android custom object list

Tags: android, list, sorting, data-manipulation

I have a list of my own class object in android class.

I want to do two things with that list.

First I want to Apply order by like this I used to do with C# code.

```
myList.orderby(x => x.energyLevel);
```

Secondly I want to fetch some data from that list. Like this

```
myList.where(x=>x.gender=="male");
```

How to do this in android?

Comment: Try to use database for easily achieving this.

Comment: TCA's answer covers sorting. Check this post thread for filtering options: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/122105/what-is-the-best-way-to-filter-a-java-collection. Unfortunately, Android's Java doesn't support lambdas yet.

Comment: yes it is but it is only for string type i want to sort by my variable which is Double

Comment: it says: "Type mismatch: cannot convert from boolean to int"

Comment: (int)obj2.energylevel - (int)obj1.energylevel solved my problem  :)
for ascending order use (int)obj1.energylevel - (int)obj2.energylevel

Comment: Oops, yeah, sorry. I misspoke.

Comment: But that give me the idea

Answer (score 1):

> `orderby` using `ArrayList` in android

```
  Collections.sort(myList, new Comparator<MyListObj>(){
  public int compare(MyListObj obj1, MyListObj obj2) {
    return obj1.x.compareToIgnoreCase(obj2.x);
  }
});
```

Comment: couldn't understand that, what this will do ?

Comment: this will sort myList according to compare() http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List)

Comment: thats great but what if my obj1.x type is double?

Comment: actually my obj1.energyLevel type is double