# How to get a sublist from a list in android using predicates?

Tags: java, android, predicate

In android I currently do this

```
    List<FishImage> newList = new ArrayList<FishImage>();
    for(FishImage image : images) {
        if (image.getApproved()) {
            newList.add(image);
        }
    }
```

But is there a way I could do something like which is pseudocode

```
List<FishImage> newList = images.getSublist(
    @Override
    public Boolean predicate(FishImage fi) {
        return fi.getApproved();
    }
);
```

Thanks

Comment: Nothing in the system libraries, I think. You could use a library like Guava or Commons Collections. Or just make a static helper method.

Comment: How would I use `Commons Collections`?

Comment: here it is: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/

Comment: Im not sure how I would write the code

Comment: Check out some of the answers over at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/122105/what-is-the-best-way-to-filter-a-java-collection?rq=1