# Filter a map based on criteria java design implementation query

Tags: java, filter

I have `Map<String,List<Object>>` and for each `key` i need to filter the `List<Object>`. When performing the filter, I need to remove items from the `List<Object>` .

I can iterate over the map and remove the elements that I want however, I also need to keep track of the elements that I have removed. I want the filter function to be simple and *only* filter, in which case you would always get a `Map<String,List<Object>>` with the filtered values. The problem is, how can I know which records have been removed?.

I can write another function to return the items which are discarded but this would mean that I would iterate twice over the same data structure. Or I can have variables inside the filter which would store the values (and then I can retrieve) but this looks messy. (i could also use the collectionUtils disjunction function - another option)

Are there other ways/design patterns that i can use for implementation?

Comment: Something like an audit trail. Do you have API or sample code around which to build an example?

Comment: All I have at present is a map iteration, if match criteria keep array list entry, else remove. Returns the filtered map. I can either iterate over the map again or use the apache commons api to give the disjunction (which returns elements which were removed). I wouldent want to use an api for the filtering, would like to implement this myself

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/122207/4624062)
1. Create an interface (or a set) to indicate which values to keep. 
2. Create the filter function to store the kept values . (you can also store the discarded ones)