# How to count number of custom objects in list which have same value for one of its attribute

Tags: java, arraylist, collections

I am programming in java. Say I have an custom object Item

```
class Item
{
     Integer id;
     BigDecimal itemNumber;
}
```

I have list of Items.

```
List<Item> items = new ArrayList<>();
```

Now, What is best way in java to know, list of `Items` contain some `Items` with same value for `itemNumber`.

Comment: use loop and match object using equals and count.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**To search for a specific item with some item number**:

```
//result list
List<Item> itemsWithSameNumber = new ArrayList<>();

for (Item item : items) {
    if (item.getItemNumber().equals(yourKey)) {
        itemsWithSameNumber.add(item);
    }
}
```

**To get lists of items for all item numbers:**

You can use a `HashMap` for this case:

```
//result map
HashMap<BigDecimal, List<Item>> map = new HashMap<>();

for (Item item : items) {
    List<Item> itemsWithSameNumber = map.get(item.getItemNumber());
    if (itemsWithSameNumber == null) { //does not exist in map yet
        itemsWithSameNumber = new ArrayList<Item>();
        map.put(item.getItemNumber(), itemsWithSameNumber);
    }
    itemsWithSameNumber.add(item); //now add the item to the list for this key
}
```

Later on, you can iterate over map's keyset and get all items for each key:

```
for (BigDecimal key : map.keySet()) {
    List<Item> listOfElementsWithSameKey = map.get(key);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't really specify what you mean with *contain some `Item` with same value for `itemNumber`*

- Sort all by `itemNumber`?
- Get all elements that match `itemNumber`?

Anyway, you have several ways to achieve this:

- use [`Predicates` to filter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sql/rowset/Predicate.html)
- or [`Comparators` to sort](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html).
- [external libraries](http://code.google.com/p/lambdaj/),
- [filter by streams](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1385698/3850595) (up to `Java8`).

Or, if you have a reference value, use plain `Java`, **like real men** do:

```
BigInteger yourValue = // your desired value
List<Item> result = new ArrayList<Item>();
for (Item item : items) {
    if (item.itemNumber.equals(yourValue)) {
        item.add(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Override **equals** method in your **Item** class and in the item list call **contains** method which will call Item's equal method.

```
 class Item
    {
         Integer id;
         BigDecimal itemNumber;

          public boolean equals(Item item) {
          if (this.itemNumber.equals(item.itemNumber)) {
            return true;
        }
    // getter and setter

}
```

In the List check

> items.contains(item)

Answer (score 0):

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ...
    // Group by Item by ItemNumber in a map Map<ItemNumber, List<Item>>
    list.stream().collect(groupingBy(Item::getItemNumber));
    // Count Items having sameItemNumber map Map<ItemNumber, Long>
    list.stream().collect(groupingBy(Item::getItemNumber, counting()));
    // Return the number of distinct ItemNumber
    list.stream().filter(filterByAttribute(Item::getItemNumber).count());
}

public static <T> Predicate<T> filterByAttribute(Function<? super T, ?> keyExtractor) {
    Map<Object, Boolean> seen = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    return (t) -> seen.putIfAbsent(keyExtractor.apply(t), Boolean.TRUE) == null;
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

to count them:

```
List<Item> items = new ArrayList<>();
int count=0;
int idToFind=88;
for(Item i:items){
  if(i.getId()==idToFind)
    count++;
}
```

to get another list:

```
Item itemToFind;
List newList=list.contains(itemToFind);
```

and override equals in your class to compare objects after big decimal