# Check whether list of custom objects have same value for a property in Java 8

Tags: java, arraylist, java-8, java-stream

I am new to Java 8. I have a list of custom objects of type A, where A is like below:

```
 class A {
      int id;
      String name;
 }
```

I would like to determine if all the objects in that list have same name. I can do it by iterating over the list and capturing previous and current value of names. In that context, I found [How to count number of custom objects in list which have same value for one of its attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31808779/how-to-count-number-of-custom-objects-in-list-which-have-same-value-for-one-of-i).  But is there any better way to do the same in java 8 using stream?

Comment: What does your actual output look like?

Comment: Actual output is either true/false.

Comment: Or use `grouppingBy` then check size. `list.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(A::getName, Collectors.toList()))`

Answer (score 34, accepted):

One way is to get the name of the first list and call `allMatch` and check against that.

```
String firstName = yourListOfAs.get(0).name;
boolean allSameName = yourListOfAs.stream().allMatch(x -> x.name.equals(firstName));
```

Comment: The most efficient + clear solution using streams, IMO.  The `allMatch` will short-circuit as soon as it finds a non-matching element.

Comment: If name can be null, add `if` statement to check `firstName` is not null and change to `allMatch(x -> firstName.equals(x.name));`.  And if `firstName` is null still have to check all other names are null. It seems with Aomine's solution those cases are covered.

Answer (score 54):

You can `map` from `A` -->  `String` , apply the `distinct` intermediate operation,  utilise `limit(2)` to enable optimisation where possible and then check if `count` is less than or equal to `1` in which case all objects have the same name and if not then they  do not all have the same name.

```
boolean result = myList.stream()
                       .map(A::getName)
                       .distinct()
                       .limit(2)
                       .count() <= 1;
```

With the example shown above, we leverage the `limit(2)` operation so that we stop as soon as we find two distinct object names.

Answer (score 12):

another way is to calculate count of distinct names using

```
boolean result = myList.stream().map(A::getName).distinct().count() == 1;
```

of course you need to add getter for 'name' field

Answer (score 2):

One more option by using **Partitioning**. Partitioning is a special kind of grouping, in which the resultant map contains at most two different groups – one for true and one for false.

by this, You can get number of matching and not matching

```
String firstName = yourListOfAs.get(0).name;

Map<Boolean, List<Employee>> partitioned =  employees.stream().collect(partitioningBy(e -> e.name==firstName));
```

**Java 9 using takeWhile**  takewhile will take all the values until the predicate returns false. this is similar to break statement in while loop

```
String firstName = yourListOfAs.get(0).name;        

        List<Employee> filterList =  employees.stream()
                                               .takeWhile(e->firstName.equals(e.name)).collect(Collectors.toList());
        if(filterList.size()==list.size())
        {
            //all objects have same values 
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Or use `groupingBy` then check `entrySet` size.

```
boolean b  = list.stream()
             .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(A::getName, 
             Collectors.toList())).entrySet().size() == 1;
```