# Find specific object in a List by attribute

Tags: java

I have a list:

```
List<UserItem> userList = new ArrayList<>();
```

Where I add the following:

```
User father = new User();
father.setName("Peter");

UserItem parent = new UserItem(father, null);
userList.add(parent);
```

I then create another user:

```
User daughter = new User();
daughter.setName("Emma");

UserItem child = new UserItem(daughter, <OBJECT IN LIST WHERE NAME IS "PETER">);
userList.add(child);
```

However, I need to change the text wrapped in `<>` above to the parent object I added before (the father), specified by the name ("Peter" in this case).

**How can I find an object in a List by a specific attribute?** In my case, how can I find the object in the List that has the name "Peter"?

Please note that I add hundreds, sometimes thousands, of different users like this to the list. Each "parent" has a unique name.

Comment: Are you sure you want a 'List'? It's certainly possible to iterate over a list to get the specific element you want, but that's not really the best way to use them. It sounds like you want a `Map<String, UserItem>`.

Comment: I agree with ruakh. To answer the question though: you need to loop over the list, and find the user that has "Peter" as its name. Surely you've done that before, in your first algorithm course.

Answer (score 11):

The obvious solution would be iterating on the list and when the condition is met, return the object:

```
for (User user : userList) {
    if ("peter".equals(user.getName()) {
        return user;
    }
}
```

And you can use `filter` (Java 8):

```
List<User> l = list.stream()
    .filter(s -> "peter".equals(s.getUser()))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

to get a list with all "peter" users.

As suggested in comments, I think using [`Map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) is a better option here.

Comment: elegant solution

Answer (score 3):

Answer to your question is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1385698/2068880

```
Stream peters = userList.stream().filter(p -> p.user.name.equals("Peter"))
```

However, as ruakh suggested, it's more reasonable to use `Map<String, UserItem>` to make it faster. Otherwise, it will iterate all the objects in the list to find users with name "Peter".

Answer (score 2):

Other way with parallelStream with findAny

```
Optional<UserItem> optional = userList.parallelStream().findAny(p -> p.user.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("Peter"));
UserItem user = optional.isPresent() ? optional.get() : null;
```