# Filter Java List in place without external libraries

Tags: java, list, collections, java-7

This question is similar to [What is the best way to filter a Java Collection?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/122105/1059070) "filter a `java.util.Collection` based on a predicate." with the additional requirements  that

- The filter be done in place (`O(1)` memory excluding the input) because the list is large
- No external libraries (i.e. Guava, Apache commons, etc.) may be used
- Java 7 compatible (no Java 8 streams)

We can make the assumption that the `java.util.Collection` type is a `java.util.List` that implements `.remove(int)`

Possible solutions:

- Use the `.remove()` method on an `Iterator` of the `List`.  This could throw an `UnsupportedOperationException` since the `.remove()` method is optionally supported on `Iterator`
- Write our own iterator that iterates through the list using an index, `.size()`, and `.remove(int)`

Are there any simpler solutions?

Is `Iterator.remove()` implemented for all standard Java `List`s and/or `Collection`s that implement `.remove(int)`?

Comment: @AndyTurner, Thanks. I've updated the last bit of my question then: "Is `Iterator.remove()` implemented for all standard Java `List`s and/or `Collection`s that implement `.remove(int)`?"

Comment: Use a for loop, but start at the end of the List and decrement to the beginning.  That way element removal doesn't impact the index counter.

Comment: @BoristheSpider It's valid as a general, non-Android specific question.  I did specify Java 7 in the question.

Comment: @arcyqwerty I can't say "all" with confidence, but `AbstractList`, `ArrayList`, `LinkedList`, `Vector` do. It would be strange if the features didn't match up between the `List` and its `Iterator`.

Comment: @Gilbert Le Blanc: iterating backwards makes a lot of things simpler but also reduces the usefulness of the operation. E.g. one task would be to remove duplicates but maintaining the ordering, i.e. keep the first one. In Java 8: `HashSet<Object> tmp=new HashSet<>(); list.removeIf(item -> !tmp.add(item));` that only works because the implementations don’t iterate backwards…

Comment: @Holger: You or I could iterate forwards through the List per your requirements because we would know to decrement the loop counter and loop limit by one for each List element removed.  Sadly, most "programmers" wouldn't even understand the concept.

Comment: @Gilbert Le Blanc: that’s why it is a good thing that the Java 8 Collections offer a ready-to-use `removeIf` implementation…

Comment: @Holger: Not everyone has migrated to Java 8.  Plenty of Java companies and their Java developers are still using Java 6 and Java 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no optimal solution that fits all `List`s and that’s where you can never reach the efficiency of Java 8, as, being an `interface` method, Java 8’s `default` method can be overridden by any `List` implementation providing an implementation tailored for that particular class.

When you want to do a reasonable implementation of a similar feature in pre-Java 8, you have to focus on the *common* cases. There are almost no JRE provided lists for which `remove(int)` works but `Iterator.remove` doesn’t<sup>1</sup>. But consider that the `ArrayList` is the most used mutable `List` implementation and for that implementation, an iterator based solution will perform poorly for large list and lots of removed items. This is because every remove operation, regardless of whether you are using `remove(int)` or `Iterator.remove`, will shift all subsequent items by one position before you can proceed and possibly will remove again an item. In the worst case, having a predicate matching all items, that would impose a quadratic complexity. So it’s important to provide a more sophisticated solution for that case:

```
interface Predicate<T> {
    boolean test(T object);
}
public static <T> boolean removeIf(List<T> list, Predicate<? super T> p) {
    if(list instanceof RandomAccess) {
        int num=list.size();
        BitSet bs=new BitSet(num);
        for(int index=0; index<num; index++) {
            if(p.test(list.get(index))) bs.set(index);
        }
        if(bs.isEmpty()) {
            return false;
        }
        for(int dst=bs.nextSetBit(0), src=dst;; dst++, src++) {
            src=bs.nextClearBit(src);
            if(src==num) {
              list.subList(dst, src).clear();
              break;
            }
            list.set(dst, list.get(src));
        }
        return true;
    }
    else {
        boolean changed=false;
        for(Iterator<T> it=list.iterator(); it.hasNext(); ) {
            if(p.test(it.next())) {
                it.remove();
                changed=true;
            }
        }
        return changed;
    }
}
```

In the case of lists implementing `RandomAccess`, which includes all arraylist style implementations, the solution will mimic something similar to Java 8’s `ArrayList.removeIf` implementation though we don’t have direct access to the internal array and I left out all fail-fast concurrent modification detection stuff. Now, for `ArrayList` kind of lists it will have linear complexity and so it will have for `LinkedList`, as it doesn’t implement `RandomAccess` and thus, will get processed using its `Iterator`.

The method also fulfills the contract of Java 8’s [`removeIf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#removeIf-java.util.function.Predicate-) method of returning whether the list has been changed by the operation.

---

<sup>1</sup> `CopyOnWriteArrayList` is an exception but for a copy-on-write list the idea of an in-place `removeIf` is moot, unless provided by the list itself, as, when implementing it via its `remove(int)` (or any other `public`) operation we’re effectively copying the entire list on each change. So in that case, copying the entire list into an ordinary list, performing the `removeIf` on that list and copying it back will be more efficient in most cases.

Comment: Note, `CopyOnWriteArrayList` allows `remove(int)` but disallows `remove()` from an iterator. Kind of surprising at first, but sensible when you think about COWAL's iterator semantics are over a *snapshot*, so any mutations would be made on a stale copy.

Comment: @Stuart Marks: good hint. Maybe it would be *better* if the operation failed for a `CopyOnWriteArrayList` but since it implements `RandomAccess`, it will work, with less than optimal performance and without protection against concurrent updates…

Answer (score 0):

`Filters` and `Predicate`s are Java8 types, so if you don't want to use Java8, you need something similar.

You could fake the filter with an wrapped `Iterator` and make it work with an object (similar to how Prediates could be implemented); however, there are secondary questions:

You state the list is quite large, and the memory impact of the solution should be `O(1)` but such a thing is impossible to guarantee without knowing the list being operated upon.  The `remove(int)` operator could allocate a new list index and copy into it, within the implementation.

Assuming the list does no such thing, the best you can do is implement your own iterator that takes a Predicate like test, or write a specific loop to handle the list.

In any case, this sounds like an interview question.  Here's one example

```
public interface MyPredicate<T> {
   public boolean isTrue(T value);
}

public void removeOnTrue(List<T> list, MyPredicate<T> predicate) {
   Iterator<T> iterator = list.iterator();
   while (iterator.hasNext()) {
      T next = iterator.next();
      if (predicate.isTrue(next)) {
         iterator.remove();
      }
   }
}
```

doing it with a for loop across indexes is about the same, except that you would then have to keep track of the index (and remove using index).

To use the above example:

```
...
List<String> names = ...;
removeOnTrue(names, new MyPredicate<String>() {
  public boolean isTrue(String value) {
    return value.startsWith("A");
  }
});
...
```

would yield a `names` with all strings starting with "A" removed.

Comment: How you loop over the List is not really important, the important part is that you wrap the test in an Object.  Follow the patterns established by `Comparator`, but instead of returning an `int` to show ordering, return a `boolean` to show inclusion in the set.