# Apache Camel - List Aggregator with filter

Tags: json, apache-camel

I am working on an Apache Camel project to load data and Webservice and construct a file from it. The basic job of getting data from service and loading to a CSV file is working fine. However because of a limitation in service, I have to filter the data on my end from service response.

With my limited knowledge on Apache camel, I tried this.

```
from("direct:start")
            .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, constant("GET"))
            .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_URI, simple(URL))
            .setHeader("Authorization", simple(KEY))
            .to(URL)
            .unmarshal(listJacksonDataFormat)
            //START - FILTER
            .split(body())
            .filter().method(DiagnosticDateFilter.class, "diagnosedAfterLastRun")
            .aggregate(constant(true), new GroupedBodyAggregationStrategy())
            .completionTimeout(1000)
            //END - FILTER
            .marshal(bindyCsvDataFormat)
            .to("file:" + FILELOC);
```

**// This filter checks one of the value from Webservice JSON Array response and decides if the model object needs to be added to output list during aggregation.**

```
public static class DiagnosticDateFilter {
    public boolean diagnosedAfterLastRun(@Body Feed feed) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

public class GroupedBodyAggregationStrategy implements AggregationStrategy {

```
@Override
public Exchange aggregate(Exchange oldExchange, Exchange newExchange) {
    Object newBody = newExchange.getIn().getBody();
    ArrayList<Object> list = null;
    if (oldExchange == null) {
        list = new ArrayList<Object>();
        list.add(newBody);
        newExchange.getIn().setBody(list);
        return newExchange;
    } else {
        list = oldExchange.getIn().getBody(ArrayList.class);
        list.add(newBody);
        return oldExchange;
    }
}
```

Some reason after "filter" and "aggregate", I am loosing data in exchange and route completes without creating file.

Is there any better way for this? Also is it possible to apply filter before `".unmarshal(listJacksonDataFormat)"` so that I don't have to include in list and then filter out? Thanks for your reply in advance!!

Comment: Likely easier to write a Java bean with a method that returns the filtered List instead of using the filter + aggregator EIP. And just call the java bean using .to(bean:xxx)

Comment: I think Claus Ibsen's comment is on the money. Use a bean and you can find inspiration for writing filter code here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/122105/what-is-the-best-way-to-filter-a-java-collection