# Converting a sql style 'Where' into filtering an arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

Originally our application had the user write a 'filter criteria' that we append to a soql query for the object as the WHERE.

Now that we are pulling all that object locally and storing it in a giant ArrayList, yet we don't want the app front end to change much. So basically the question is, is there any decent solution to do something like:

```
ArrayList <object> filtered = filter ("Field1='bob' AND Field2 != 'bill'", originalList)
```

Preferably out of the box or other free solution. Was originally thinking of doing some complicated if statement but parsing the String seems like a pain manually.

Comment: I think the answer to this question can help you:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/122105/what-is-the-best-way-to-filter-a-java-collection

Comment: Yeah, had that one, too, but there's still the problem with parsing the `SQL` syntax. It shouldn't bee too hard, as long as it's only the `WHERE` clause, but I don't know of any standard implementation.

Comment: yeah, ideally a way to parse the syntax would be ideal because otherwise its gonna be some crazy amount of switch case or something.