# How to filter a list by multiple properties in Java?

Tags: java, sorting, lambda

I'm  trying to make use of Java's functional library to filter out some entries from a List.

I have a list of Book objects, ordered first by a Book ID and then by a Revision Number.  Example below where I have nine Book objects in the list.

```
Book: ID 1, Revision Number 1
Book: ID 1, Revision Number 2
Book: ID 1, Revision Number 3
Book: ID 2, Revision Number 1
Book: ID 2, Revision Number 2
Book: ID 2, Revision Number 3
Book: ID 3, Revision Number 1
Book: ID 3, Revision Number 2
Book: ID 3, Revision Number 3
```

I'd like to filter the list so that I only have the highest Revision Number for each Book ID.

```
Book: ID 1, Revision Number 3
Book: ID 2, Revision Number 3
Book: ID 3, Revision Number 3
```

Does Java have some functional capability using something like filter or a Comparator to allow me to filter based on multiple fields, based on a common value (Book ID)?  I'd like to try and avoid having to write my own function to loop over the Collection and do the filtering if possible...  Any suggestions?

Comment: Maybe a `TreeSet` with some comparator

Comment: You can collect it to map with merge function, is it feasible?

Comment: If you are using java 8 and know the value to filter by beforehand, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122105/what-is-the-best-way-to-filter-a-java-collection the solution based on [Collection.removeIf()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#removeIf-java.util.function.Predicate-) might be best suited for what you want

Comment: You can do something like `books.stream().collect(groupingBy(Book::getId, maxBy(Comparator.comparing(Book::getRevision))))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about something like this:

```
List<Book> books = Arrays.asList(
        new Book(1, 2),
        new Book(1, 3),
        new Book(2, 2),
        new Book(2, 3)
);

System.out.println(
    books.stream()
            .collect(
                    groupingBy(Book::getID,
                        maxBy(comparingInt(Book::getRevison))
                    )
            )

);// {1=Optional[Book{ID=1, revison=3}], 2=Optional[Book{ID=2, revison=3}]}
```

Update if at the end you just need a `List<Book>` just use stream on values of the `Map<Integer,Optinal<Book>>`

```
.values().stream().map(Optional::get).collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

the full example :

```
System.out.println(books.stream()
                .collect(
                        groupingBy(Book::getID,
                                maxBy(comparingInt(Book::getRevison))
                        )
                ).values()
                .stream()
                .map(Optional::get)
                .collect(Collectors.toList())
);
```

Comment: Looks to do what I want, though I should have specified, it needs to return the new, sorted List<Book>, which doesn't seem to be possible with this approach?

Comment: @deanmau5, it is possible please see my update for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a true filtering based on more than one property but can be feasible to your problem:

```
final Map<String, Book> books = list.stream().collect(
    Collectors.toMap(
        b -> b.getId(), 
        b -> b,
        (b1, b2) -> {
            if(b1.getNumber() > b2.getNumber()) {
                return b1;
            }
            return b2;
        })
);
```

It will return map which contains id as key, and Book with highest number (with unique id).

In `toMap` collector you can add `merge function` which will decide what to do when collision on same key occurs. In this situation it will return book with higher number.

If you want collection from that call `values()`.

Comment: `groupingBy()` is better suited for this. See my comment above.

Comment: Agree, but still, you have to create comparator to `Collectors.maxBy()`.