# Java collection that includes instances of subclasses

Tags: java, collections

I need to use a collection of subclasses of basic class here is the description of the problem:

```
class A {
}

class B extends A{
}

class C extends A{
}

class D extends A{
}
```

I need to use a collection that I can get an instance of a subclass by its type only that mean when I need to get an instance of A class from the collection I need to get like this:

```
c.get(B.class);
```

If I have more than one instance from the same type I want to retrieve the instance by type and index:
Examples: `c.get(B.class, 0), c.get(B.class, 1), c.get(C.class)`

Any help.

Comment: the question is unclear.  you say " use a collection of subclasses" . the collection holds the classes or instances of them? there is no API to get an item from a Java collection based on its type. can you provide more info on the usecase?

Comment: You probably just have to filter your collection with checking in predicate that actual object is instanceof the type you need.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122105/what-is-the-best-way-to-filter-a-java-collection

Comment: @SharonBenAsher the collection should contain an instance of the subclasses, but I need to retrieve an instance by its type and index if there is more than one instance from the same type.

Comment: You could write such a collection class. Or are you asking whether Java  includes such a collection class?

Answer (score 1):

That would be best accomplished using Map and List

```
Map<Class, List<? extends A>> map = new HashMap<>()
```

You will then add element like this:

```
void addElement(final A element)
    if (!map.containsKey(element.getClass())){
        map.put(element.getClass(), new LinkedList<>());
    }    
    map.get(element.getClass()).add(element);
}
```

and you will be able to get n-th instance of particular class by

```
map.get(<Class here>).get(n);
```

I don't know of any implementation of a Collection, which would provide the convenient method `get(key, index)` so you will probably have to code it yourself.

Comment: `Class` is a raw type. You should use `Class<?>`

Answer (score 1):

As noted in other answer, you can do it as Map, otherwise you can also extend a collection yourself - this sadly doesn't really allow you to use eg. List interface to call it, but it works if you use the class itself. It would look something like this:

```
class InstanceArrayList<T> extends ArrayList<T>
{
    public <V> V get(Class<V> instanceClass){
        return (V) this.stream()
            .filter( e -> e.getClass().equals( instanceClass ) )
            .findFirst()
            .orElse( null );
    }

    public <V> V get(Class<V> instanceClass, int index){
        return (V) this.stream()
            .filter( e -> e.getClass().equals( instanceClass ) )
            .skip( index ).findFirst()
            .orElse( null );
    }
}
```

It will warn you about unchecked cast - but we can ignore it safely, since we already know the object type matches.

And then you can just use it like this:

```
public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        InstanceArrayList<A> it = new InstanceArrayList<>();
        it.add( new A() );
        it.add( new A() );
        it.add( new B() );
        it.add( new B() );
        it.add( new C() );
        it.add( new C() );

        System.out.println(it.get( A.class ));
        System.out.println(it.get( A.class, 1 ));
        System.out.println(it.get( B.class ));
        System.out.println(it.get( B.class, 1 ));
        System.out.println(it.get( C.class ));
        System.out.println(it.get( C.class, 1 ));

    }
```

If you don't want it to return child class, you can also easly make it return T (superclass) instead.

Answer (score 0):

It looks as if the thing you were looking for is Java's `Map<K, V>`. Shortly, it is a collection of key-value pairs. You can store values by invoking `put(K, V)` and access them by invoking `V get(K)` Most common implementation is `HashMap`.
However, you won't be able to use `Map<Class<T>, T>>` as it will not give you an ability to store multiple values for a single key, so you solution would be storing collections of values as your map's values. 
For this you would require king of lazy initialization of the collection such as having `map.computeIfAbsent(key, k -> new ArrayList<>())` for `Map Map<Class<T>, Collection<T>>`