# How to create an arraylist satisfying a condition using lambda expression

Tags: java

I have to write a method body of class Employee containing 3 objects and return an arraylist of employees whose attendance is greater than 70% using lambda expression.

Java

```
public List<Employee> findAttendance(List<Employee> emp) {
    List<Employee> l = new ArrayList<Employee>();
    l.forEach(emp -> (if(emp.getAttendance() >= 70)) {
            l.add(emp);
     });
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122105/what-is-the-best-way-to-filter-a-java-collection

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the best way to filter a Java Collection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122105/what-is-the-best-way-to-filter-a-java-collection)

Answer (score 1):

```
List<Employee> empsWithGoodAttendance = l.stream()
                                          .filter(e -> e.getAttendance() >= 70)
                                          .collect(Collectors.toList());
```