# Searching registers that contains a part of text inside a registers from a List with stream java 8

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have this POJO. Also, I have a List of Students and I want to filter with stream which registers have in his schoolname the text `santa`. In SQL it would be something like this: `LIKE %SANTA%`

```
  public class Student {
    private String name;
    private String lastName;
    private String city;
    private String schoolname;
    private String telephone;

    public String getName() {
      return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
      this.name = name;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
      return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
      this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getCity() {
      return city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
      this.city = city;
    }

    public String getSchoolname() {
      return schoolname;
    }

    public void setSchoolname(String schoolname) {
      this.schoolname = schoolname;
    }

    public String getTelephone() {
      return telephone;
    }

    public void setTelephone(String telephone) {
       this.telephone = telephone;
    }
}
```

And I would like to obtain the students which his `schoolname` contains the string `santa`, do you know how can I have to do the filter with streams?

I need to do with stream, I can't do it with if and else statements.

Comment: Have you tried to do something with streams?

Comment: you can use `filter()` with a Regex `match()`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the best way to filter a Java Collection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122105/what-is-the-best-way-to-filter-a-java-collection)

Comment: If you need a tutorial with text and video, here it is - http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-functional-programming/streams.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `stream()` and `filter()` where `students` is list of Student object.

```
students.stream().filter(student->student.getSchoolname().contains("santa")).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 1):

Stream over the `List` and apply a `filter()` that checks whether the school name of a `Student` contains "SANTA".

```
List<School> input = ...
List<School> output = 
    input.stream()
         .filter(s -> s.getSchoolname().contains("SANTA"))
         .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

If you want this filter not to be case sensitive, you can write

```
.filter(s -> s.getSchoolname().toUpperCase().contains("SANTA"))
```

If you want both the `List` that contains "SANTA" and the `List` that doesn't contain it, you can use `Collectors.partitioningBy()`:

```
List<School> input = ...
Map<Boolean,List<School>> output = 
    input.stream()
         .collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(s -> s.getSchoolname().contains("SANTA")));
```

Comment: Very grateful, also I need to know how can I get the registers that NOT CONTAINS the string "santa", could you help me please @Eran

Comment: @fmd89 see edit

Comment: very grateful @Eran Thank you very much!!!!