# How to recyclerView Item on the basis of boolean parameter and only display true items?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I have a question that how can I sort Arraylist in on the basis of boolean parameter and only display true items. `datasource.sortByDescending { it.favorite }` Here I am getting sorted array in which I got true items on top and false items on bottom. What I want is that it only display true items and not display false items.

I hope I am clear with my question.

Full Code is below:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    rvlist.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this,LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,false)
    val datasource = getDataSource()
    val beneficiaryAdapter = BeneficiaryAdapter(datasource)
    rvlist.adapter = beneficiaryAdapter

    btnAll.setOnClickListener{
        btnFavorite.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE)
        btnAll.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN)
        btnSortByFrequency.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE)
        btnSortByName.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE)

        rvlist.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this,LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,false)
        val datasource = getDataSource()
        val beneficiaryAdapter = BeneficiaryAdapter(datasource)
        rvlist.adapter = beneficiaryAdapter
    }

    btnFavorite.setOnClickListener{
        btnFavorite.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN)
        btnAll.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE)
        btnSortByFrequency.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE)
        btnSortByName.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE)

        rvlist.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this,LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,false)
        val datasource = getDataSource()
        datasource.sortByDescending { it.favorite }
        val beneficiaryAdapter = BeneficiaryAdapter(datasource)
        rvlist.adapter = beneficiaryAdapter
    }

    btnSortByFrequency.setOnClickListener{
        btnFavorite.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE)
        btnAll.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE)
        btnSortByFrequency.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN)
        btnSortByName.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE)

        rvlist.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this,LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,false)
        val datasource = getDataSource()
        datasource.sortByDescending { it.frequency }
        val beneficiaryAdapter = BeneficiaryAdapter(datasource)
        rvlist.adapter = beneficiaryAdapter
    }

    btnSortByName.setOnClickListener{
        btnFavorite.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE)
        btnAll.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE)
        btnSortByFrequency.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE)
        btnSortByName.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN)

        rvlist.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this,LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,false)
        val datasource = getDataSource()
        datasource.sortBy { it.name }
        val beneficiaryAdapter = BeneficiaryAdapter(datasource)
        rvlist.adapter = beneficiaryAdapter
    }

}

private fun getDataSource():ArrayList<beneficiary>{
    val list = ArrayList<beneficiary>()
    list.add(beneficiary(1, "Adbul Malik", "12346564555124", "Meezan",true,5))
    list.add(beneficiary(2, "Naeem Ali", "6454886614281", "HBL",true,5))
    list.add(beneficiary(3, "Ali Raza", "456467864568465", "Soneri",false,4))
    list.add(beneficiary(4, "Talha Abid", "46873456465464564", "Allied",false,1))
    list.add(beneficiary(5, "Hassan Ali", "16456464564646", "Meezan",false,5))
    list.add(beneficiary(6, "Shahid Khan", "78946756195845648", "HBL",true,3))
    list.add(beneficiary(7, "Umer Riaz", "79464567754379", "Soneri",false,6))
    list.add(beneficiary(8, "Zeeshan Farooq", "797536187897465", "Allied",false,1))
    list.add(beneficiary(9, "Qasim Ali", "551988763478565746765", "MCB",false,1))
    list.add(beneficiary(10, "Farooq Haider", "81786523478465010", "Punjab",false,2))

    return list
}
```

}

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to filter a Java Collection (based on predicate)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122105/how-to-filter-a-java-collection-based-on-predicate)

Comment: I can't understand this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can basically filter your array list as below

```kotlin
getDataSource().filter { it.favorite }
```

You can update your code as below:

```kotlin
btnFavorite.setOnClickListener{
        btnFavorite.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN)
        btnAll.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE)
        btnSortByFrequency.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE)
        btnSortByName.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE)

        rvlist.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this,LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,false)
        val beneficiaryAdapter = BeneficiaryAdapter(getDataSource().filter { it.favorite })
        rvlist.adapter = beneficiaryAdapter
    }
```

This won't update your `dataSource` variable after you tried to change. You have to put it into new variable or directly use it on where you are going to use

```kotlin
val datasource = getDataSource()
datasource.sortByDescending { it.frequency }
```

Comment: I doesn't help. it stay as it is.

Comment: I have tested and it works. You probably do it on variable directly, but it doesn't update your old variable as you have did.

I have updated my code, if still has issues, let me know