# How to search in a custom built arraylist?

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an arraylist built like this:

In class: Strings.java

```
ArrayList<MyQueue> strings = new ArrayList<MyQueue>();
strings.add (new MyQueue("paper", "clips", "eraser"));
strings.add (new MyQueue("paperplane", "numbers", "pineapple"));
```

In class: MyQueue.java

```
--Constructor with 3 string parameters--
--Getters/setters for three strings--
```

Now in the Strings.java class, I want to search my ArrayList "strings" to see if it has the string "paper"?

How could I do this efficiently?

Comment: To be honest, I am new to Java and I am uncertain. My idea is to get each object MyQueue in a loop and see if it has that String I want. any easier way?

Comment: Yes ur idea us also good. I see you ave some answers now!

Answer (score 0):

iterate through `strings` to get each `MyQueue` and then iterate through the elements in each `MyQueue` to see if it has "paper"

```
for(MyQueue mq:strings){
   if(mq.getString1().equals("paper") ||
      mq.getString2().equals("paper") ||
      mq.getString3().equals("paper") )

      return true;
}
return false;
```

where getString#() is the method for getting each of the `Strings` in `MyQueue`

Answer (score 0):

You should try to override the `equals` method to compare the objects using the first attribute. And then call `contains` method to check for the object that has "paper" attribute. `contains` method uses `equals` internally so that's the reason you need to override equals.

Comment: How can I override the equals method? Should it be done in the MyQueue class where the arraylist is?

Comment: @user2779837 Yes you need to override in MyQueue class. Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8322129/arraylists-custom-contains-method