# android check if value is in list

Tags: android, arrays

in my android app, i would like to check, if a value is already in my array list.

i tried something like this:

```
private List<Values> retrieve() {


        List<Values> list = new ArrayList<>();

        int x = 0;
        while (x < Values.length) {
            if (list.contains(new Values(Values[x]))) {
                Log.e("-->", "DUPLICATE: "+Values[x]);
            } else {
                Log.e("-->", "NEW: "+Values[x]);
                list.add(new Values(Values[x]));
            }
            x++;
        }
        return list;

    }
```

The content of my ArrayList "Values":

> Max,Sabine,Chris,Max,Max

But i always get the Log "NEW".
but this can't be right. The Value "Max" is an duplicate.

What is my mistake?

Comment: why you use new Values(Values[x])  ? why not use directly check with Values[x]

Comment: I think to get it work need to override `hashCode ` and `equals ` methods in `Values ` class. see following post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8322129/arraylists-custom-contains-method probably help

Comment: Why do you use List? Should be try set, map etc dictionary collections. If you will use list, you could creafully about object hashcode values.

Answer (score 0):

Don't create a new object.

```
int x = 0;
while (x < Values.length) {
    if (list.contains(Values[x])) {
        Log.e("-->", "DUPLICATE: "+Values[x]);
    } else {
        Log.e("-->", "NEW: "+Values[x]);
        list.add(Values[x]);
    }
    x++;
}
return list;
```

But best would be to not allow duplicates to be stored. You can use a [LinkedHashSet](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html) for that (if you want it ordered). Else just a `HashSet` would do fine.