# How to apply contains function on attribute of a Java Object?

Tags: java, list, contains

I have `Address` class as:

```
public class Address{
    private String city;
    private String pincode;
    private String state;
}
```

I have an attribute of different object `request` as `private List<Address> transitLocations`.

How can I check if `transitLocations` contains an address which is having state equals to `"SomeString"` in one line.

PS: Please assume all getters & setters are present in code.
I don't want to override equals because `Address` class is used at other places too.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ArrayList's custom Contains method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8322129/arraylists-custom-contains-method)

Comment: @DurgeshSuthar Are you trying to check whether the arraylist contains an address object with the same city, pincode and state?

Comment: @user3437460: not all properties, Just state.

Comment: @DmitryP. I don't want to override equals function. Updated question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<sub>Not being sure why solutions using `filter` and `collect` have been proposed...</sub>

You can use a  [`Predicate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Predicate.html) and pass it to [`Stream#anyMatch`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#anyMatch-java.util.function.Predicate-)

```
public boolean containsAddressWithState(
    Collection<? extends Address> collection, String state)
{
    return collection.stream().anyMatch(a -> a.getState().equals(state));
}
```

Comment: This is better. Thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

```
public boolean containsAddressWithState(List<Address> list, String state){
    return list.stream().filter(o -> o.getState().equals(state)).findFirst().isPresent();
}
```

Or, if you really want to do it in one single line:

```
boolean containsState = transitLocations.stream().filter(o -> o.getState().equals("SomeString")).findFirst().isPresent();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can override the [public boolean equals(Object o)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) method of Object class in Address as :

```
public boolean equals(Object o){
        if(o instanceof Address && ((Address)o).getSomeString().equalsIgnoreCase(this.someString)){
            return true;
        }else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

then you can use [List.contains(Object o)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#contains(java.lang.Object)) method of List to verify that element(Address obj) is present or not in the list.

Comment: Then you hurt reusability of Address class. Equals method should verify city, pincode and state to be consistent.

Comment: @andrucz it's depend on OP requirement how he wants his Address to be equal

Comment: Yes, but it's not generally a good ideia to make equals and hashCode method based on how object will be used in a specific place. Considering that exist simple ways to do what OP wants without hurting reusability, I would avoid doing like your in answer.

Comment: @ShekharKhairnar: andrucz is correct. Many other classes use Address class, and there this is not the case.

Comment: @Durgesh Suthar: It's totally depends on the requirement and functionality. If your requirement for the equality is specific for a particular  attribute  for this case only you can go ahead with andrucz solution.