# How to filter list using Predicate

Tags: java

```
private static class FilterByStringContains implements Predicate<String> {
        private String filterString;
        private FilterByStringContains(final String filterString) {
            this.filterString = filterString;
        }
        @Override
        public boolean apply(final String string) {
            return string.contains(filterString);
        }
    }
```

I have a list of Strings, I want to filter it by the specified String so the returned value contains a list of only the specified strings. I was going to use a predicate as above but not sure how to apply this to filter a list

Comment: Check out this [SO queston](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/587404/java-finding-objects-in-collections) -- sounds like exactly what you are after.

Comment: are you using `Guava` or `org.apache.commons.collections.Predicate`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm assuming the `Predicate` here is from [Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com)? If so, you could use [`Iterables.filter`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v11.0.2/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html#filter%28java.lang.Iterable,%20com.google.common.base.Predicate%29):

```
Iterable<String> filtered = Iterables.filter(original, predicate);
```

Then build a list from that if you wanted:

```
List<String> filteredCopy = Lists.newArrayList(filtered);
```

... but I'd *only* suggest copying it to another list if you actually want it as a list. If you're just going to iterate over it (and only once), stick to the iterable.

Answer (score 4):

How about using Guava's [filter](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Collections2.html#filter%28java.util.Collection,%20com.google.common.base.Predicate%29) method or Apache commons' [filter](https://commons.apache.org/collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections/CollectionUtils.html#filter%28java.util.Collection,%20org.apache.commons.collections.Predicate%29) method? Guava's method returns a view of the collection, whereas Apache Commons' modifies the collection in-place. Don't reinvent the wheel!

Comment: To clarify, Guava's method returns a _view_, which is sort of a new collection, but doesn't explicitly do the construction.