# Matcher on multiple properties simultaneously on a Collection

Tags: java, junit, hamcrest

Is possible to test multiple condition on each Matched item in a `Collection`?

I have a collection with given objects:

> obj1: property1=A1, property2=B1
>
> obj2: property1=A2, property2=B2
>
> obj3: property1=A3, property2=B3
>
> obj4: property1=A4, property2=B4

I want to check that `property1` and `property2` have simultaneously specified values.

Thank you for any advice.

Comment: If you create a [custom matcher](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/CustomMatcher.html) then you can do whatever you want to match the objects. Have you tried this? If so, what happened?

Comment: Custom property-matching with example code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/587404/java-finding-objects-in-collections

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, that's possible. It would look something like this:

```
Matcher<Item> matcher = new BaseMatcher<Item>() {

    @Override
    public boolean matches(Object item) {
        Item myItem = (Item) item;
        return check(myItem.property1, myItem.property2);
    }

    @Override
    public void describeTo(Description description) {
        // describe it
    }

}
```

The `check` function would have to test the combination of `property1` and `property2`. This may be easiest using a `HashMap`, unless of course there's some way of calculating one from the other or something like that.